# How can I provide a "callback" to an API?

Tags: python, callback

I was reading some [module documentation](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30/) and saw something I didn't understand, in the explanation of parameters for a method:

> `callback` - callback function which will be called with argument
> list equal to `callbackargs+(result,)`
> as soon as calculation is done
> `callbackargs` - additional arguments for callback function
> group - job group, is used when `wait(group)` is called to wait for
> jobs in a given group to finish

How can I call the method and correctly supply arguments for these parameters? What are they used for, and how does this "callback" scheme work?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

A callback is a function provided by the consumer of an API that the API can then turn around and invoke (calling you back). If I setup a Dr.'s appointment, I can give them my phone number, so they can call me the day before to confirm the appointment. A callback is like that, except instead of just being a phone number, it can be arbitrary instructions like "send me an email at this address, and also call my secretary and have her put it in my calendar.

Callbacks are often used in situations where an action is asynchronous. If you need to call a function, and immediately continue working, you can't sit there wait for its return value to let you know what happened, so you provide a callback. When the function is done completely its asynchronous work it will then invoke your callback with some predetermined arguments (usually some you supply, and some about the status and result of the asynchronous action you requested).

If the Dr. is out of the office, or they are still working on the schedule, rather than having me wait on hold until he gets back, which could be several hours, we hang up, and once the appointment has been scheduled, they call me.

In this specific case, the documented method will compute the `result`, put it together with any `callbackargs` specified, and call `callback`, passing it those values as the arguments.

Comment: This gets a big upvote from me (still only worth the same as any other upvote though) for a very understandable analogy that will probably be helpful for beginners or anyone new to this technique.

Comment: This is a very good explanation for beginners, it just lacks one thing - a sample code. Now that a beginner knows what it is, could you please give us a simple example of what it would look like using your analog as function names ea: `callDoctor() callPatientBack()` etc

Comment: For more theoretical, language-agnostic explanations, please see [What is a callback function?](/questions/824234/). I tried to fix the question to make the practical aspect - how to use the API in question - as clear as possible.

Answer (score 21):

If you want some code to be executed as soon as the result is ready, put that code into a function and pass it as the `callback` argument. For example, supposing no other arguments are needed for that function:

```
def itsdone(result):
    print(f"Done! result={result}")
...
submit(..., callback=itsdone)
```

For more on how this works in Python, see e.g. [my presentation](http://www.listal.com/video/8878369) on the topic.

Comment: Don't you mean "at the time" instead of "as long"?

Comment: I meant "as soon as", just like the docs I quoted -- let me edit to fix, thanks!

Comment: Can you please repost the presentation link?

Comment: @AlexMartelli, presentation link is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the link, just looks like a hook which is called.

> callback - callback function which
>   will be called with argument 
>           list equal to callbackargs+(result,) 
>           as soon as calculation is done

The "as soon as calculation is done" bit seems ambiguous. The point, as far as I can see of this thing is that the `submit()` call distributes work to other servers and then returns. Because the finishing is asynchronous, rather block, it allows you to provide a function which is called when some unit of work finishes. If you do:

```
submit( ..., callback=work_finished, ... )
```

Then submit will ensure `work_finished()` is called when the unit of distributed work is completed on the target server.

When you call `submit()` you can provide a **callback** which is called in the same runtime as the caller of `submit()` ... and it is called after the distribution of the workload function is complete.

Kind of like "call foo(x,y) when you have done some stuff in submit()"

But yea, the documentation could be better. Have a ganders at the ppython source and see at which point the callback is called in `submit()`

Answer (score 2):

A callback is simply a function. In Python, functions are just more objects, and so the name of a function can be used as a variable, like so:

```
def func():
    ...

something(func)
```

Note that many functions which accept a callback as an argument usually require that the callback accept certain arguments. In this case, the callback function will need to accept a list of arguments specified in callbackargs.

Answer (score 2):

A [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_function) is a function you define that's later called by a function you call.

As an example, consider how AJAX works: you write code that calls a back-end server function. At some point in the future, it returns from that function (the "A" stands for Asynchronous, which is what the "Parallel" in "Parallel Python" is all about). Now - because your code calls the code on the server, you want it to tell you when it's done, and you want to do something with its results. It does so by calling your *callback function*.

When the called function completes, the standard way for it to tell you it's done is for you to tell it to call a function in your code. That's the callback function, and its job is to handle the results/output from the lower-level function you've called.