# How can I extract a single value from a nested data structure (such as from parsing JSON)?

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I wrote some code to get data from a web API. I was able to parse the JSON data from the API, but the result I gets looks quite complex. Here is one example:

```
>>> my_json
{'name': 'ns1:timeSeriesResponseType', 'declaredType': 'org.cuahsi.waterml.TimeSeriesResponseType', 'scope': 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope', 'value': {'queryInfo': {'creationTime': 1349724919000, 'queryURL': 'http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/', 'criteria': {'locationParam': '[ALL:103232434]', 'variableParam': '[00060, 00065]'}, 'note': [{'value': '[ALL:103232434]', 'title': 'filter:sites'}, {'value': '[mode=LATEST, modifiedSince=null]', 'title': 'filter:timeRange'}, {'value': 'sdas01', 'title': 'server'}]}}, 'nil': False, 'globalScope': True, 'typeSubstituted': False}
```

Looking through this data, I can see the specific data I want: the `1349724919000` value that is labelled as `'creationTime'`.

How can I write code that directly gets this value?

I don't need any searching logic to find this value. I can see what I need when I look at the response; I just need to know how to translate that into specific code to extract the specific value, in a hard-coded way. I read some tutorials, so I understand that I need to use `[]` to access elements of the nested lists and dictionaries; but I can't figure out exactly how it works for a complex case.

More generally, how can I figure out what the "path" is to the data, and write the code for it?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For reference, let's see what the original JSON would look like, with pretty formatting:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(my_json, indent=4))
{
    "name": "ns1:timeSeriesResponseType",
    "declaredType": "org.cuahsi.waterml.TimeSeriesResponseType",
    "scope": "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope",
    "value": {
        "queryInfo": {
            "creationTime": 1349724919000,
            "queryURL": "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/",
            "criteria": {
                "locationParam": "[ALL:103232434]",
                "variableParam": "[00060, 00065]"
            },
            "note": [
                {
                    "value": "[ALL:103232434]",
                    "title": "filter:sites"
                },
                {
                    "value": "[mode=LATEST, modifiedSince=null]",
                    "title": "filter:timeRange"
                },
                {
                    "value": "sdas01",
                    "title": "server"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "nil": false,
    "globalScope": true,
    "typeSubstituted": false
}
```

That lets us see the structure of the data more clearly.

In the specific case, first we want to look at the corresponding value under the `'value'` key in our parsed data. That is another dict; we can access the value of its `'queryInfo'` key in the same way, and similarly the `'creationTime'` from there.

To get the desired value, we simply put those accesses one after another:

```
my_json['value']['queryInfo']['creationTime'] # 1349724919000
```

Answer (score 22):

> I just need to know how to translate that into specific code to extract the specific value, in a hard-coded way.

If you access the API again, the new data might not match the code's expectation. You may find it useful to add some error handling. For example, use `.get()` to access dictionaries in the data, rather than indexing:

```
name = my_json.get('name') # will return None if 'name' doesn't exist
```

Another way is to test for a key explicitly:

```
if 'name' in resp_dict:
    name = resp_dict['name']
else:
    pass
```

However, these approaches may fail if further accesses are required. A placeholder result of `None` isn't a dictionary or a list, so attempts to access it that way will fail again (with `TypeError`). Since "Simple is better than complex" and "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission", the straightforward solution is to use exception handling:

```
try:
    creation_time = my_json['value']['queryInfo']['creationTime']
except (TypeError, KeyError):
    print("could not read the creation time!")
    # or substitute a placeholder, or raise a new exception, etc.
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of loading a single value from simple JSON data, and converting back and forth to JSON:

```
import json

# load the data into an element
data={"test1": "1", "test2": "2", "test3": "3"}

# dumps the json object into an element
json_str = json.dumps(data)

# load the json to a string
resp = json.loads(json_str)

# print the resp
print(resp)

# extract an element in the response
print(resp['test1'])
```

Comment: I edited this answer to add some explanation and make the code a bit neater, but it's still not very useful. It seems that OP already understood how to handle simple cases, from reading some other tutorials; the question is about how to handle nesting in the data structure.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

Here, I fetch only **statecode** from the COVID API (a JSON array).

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')

x = r.json()['statewise']

for i in x:
  print(i['statecode'])
```

Comment: What is the *"the COVID API"*? Can you elaborate a little bit? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67092033/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from functools import reduce
import re


def deep_get_imps(data, key: str):
    split_keys = re.split("[\\[\\]]", key)
    out_data = data
    for split_key in split_keys:
        if split_key == "":
            return out_data
        elif isinstance(out_data, dict):
            out_data = out_data.get(split_key)
        elif isinstance(out_data, list):
            try:
                sub = int(split_key)
            except ValueError:
                return None
            else:
                length = len(out_data)
                out_data = out_data[sub] if -length <= sub < length else None
        else:
            return None
    return out_data


def deep_get(dictionary, keys):
    return reduce(deep_get_imps, keys.split("."), dictionary)
```

Then you can use it like below:

```
res = {
    "status": 200,
    "info": {
        "name": "Test",
        "date": "2021-06-12"
    },
    "result": [{
        "name": "test1",
        "value": 2.5
    }, {
        "name": "test2",
        "value": 1.9
    },{
        "name": "test1",
        "value": 3.1
    }]
}

>>> deep_get(res, "info")
{'name': 'Test', 'date': '2021-06-12'}
>>> deep_get(res, "info.date")
'2021-06-12'
>>> deep_get(res, "result")
[{'name': 'test1', 'value': 2.5}, {'name': 'test2', 'value': 1.9}, {'name': 'test1', 'value': 3.1}]
>>> deep_get(res, "result[2]")
{'name': 'test1', 'value': 3.1}
>>> deep_get(res, "result[-1]")
{'name': 'test1', 'value': 3.1}
>>> deep_get(res, "result[2].name")
'test1'
```

Comment: This is an interesting code project, but being able to write `deep_get(res, "result[2].name")` and have it work doesn't seem like an improvement over just directly asking for `res['result'][2]['name']`.