# How can I request a specific element from an API in a GET request?

Tags: python, json, google-maps-api-3, python-requests

Here's a couple lines of a larger program

```
results = requests.get("https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=12.919082641601562,77.65169525146484|12.918915748596191,77.6517105102539|12.918656349182129,77.65177154541016|12.918524742126465,77.6517562866211|12.918295860290527,77.65178680419922|12.918216705322266,77.65177154541016|12.918027877807617,77.65178680419922||12.91647720336914,77.65180206298828|12.91647720336914,77.65180206298828|12.916269302368164,77.65177154541016|12.916149139404297,77.65178680419922|12.916014671325684,77.65177917480469|12.91580867767334,77.65179443359375|12.915785789489746,77.65182495117188|12.913755416870117,77.65186309814453|12.913578987121582,77.65186309814453|12.913309097290039,77.65184783935547|12.913025856018066,77.65186309814453|12.912832260131836,77.65187072753906|12.912651062011719,77.65190124511719|12.912428855895996,77.65188598632812|12.912148475646973,77.65184020996094|12.9120512008667,77.65180206298828|12.91196060180664,77.65179443359375|12.911927223205566,77.65165710449219|12.911907196044922,77.6515884399414|12.911901473999023,77.65150451660156|12.91188907623291,77.65132904052734|12.911890029907227,77.65113067626953|12.911898612976074,77.65096282958984|12.911872863769531,77.6508560180664||12.912422180175781,77.64830&key=AIzaSyAmplaUG26XJGwPrLbky2bHQ-eBmQvZUVU")

print(results.json())
```

Output:

```
{'snappedPoints': 
    [
       {'location': {'latitude': 12.919082345679861, 'longitude': 77.65168471404562}, 'originalIndex': 0, 'placeId': 'ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.918915069015311, 'longitude': 77.65169005380653}, 'originalIndex': 1, 'placeId': 'ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.91865394531316, 'longitude': 77.65169918497911}, 'originalIndex': 2, 'placeId': 'ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.91852299728483, 'longitude': 77.65170376406233}, 'originalIndex': 3, 'placeId': 'ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.918293368390502, 'longitude': 77.65171179387626}, 'originalIndex': 4, 'placeId': 'ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.918214811587053, 'longitude': 77.65171454089874}, 'originalIndex': 5, 'placeId': 'ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.91802528954814, 'longitude': 77.65172119976897}, 'originalIndex': 6, 'placeId': 'ChIJY0KcOIIUrjsRkOk78pj9o5I'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.917911987935893, 'longitude': 77.65172590496891}, 'originalIndex': 7, 'placeId': 'ChIJY0KcOIIUrjsRkOk78pj9o5I'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.917772027120648, 'longitude': 77.65173171726882}, 'originalIndex': 8, 'placeId': 'ChIJY0KcOIIUrjsRkOk78pj9o5I'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.917657472888019, 'longitude': 77.65173647447801}, 'originalIndex': 9, 'placeId': 'ChIJY0KcOIIUrjsRkOk78pj9o5I'}, {'location': {'latitude': 12.917551187179303, 'longitude': 77.65174088830797}, 'originalIndex': 10, 'placeId': ...
    ]
}
```

Now I need to specifically request the 'latitude' and 'longitude' parts of the webpage, and store them in a set. Any idea on how do I call these individual elements?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the short answer is, you can not do this simply from the `get` request. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552394/get-specific-json-elements-with-requests) explains it very nicely.

This means that you would have to `get` the entire json table, and obtain the `latitude` and `longitude` values locally.

```
snappoints = results.json()['snappedPoints']
myset = set()
for point in snappoints:
    # this is each individual element in snapPoints array
    myset.add((point['location']['latitude'], point['location']['longitude']))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that procedure?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the latitude and longitude for each location in the snappedPoints array.

You could use the built-in JSON decoder provided by the Requests module: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Or you could use Python's JSON module if you prefer: [2.7 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) | [3.6 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Once you've decoded the JSON response you can just iterate over your locations and grab the parts you want.

Comment: I have already decoded it, as you can see in the question. Can you help me out with the iteration?