# How can I print specific values from a json file with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new using python and I would like to know how can I print some values from my json file using python, the following is my json file:

```json
{
    "igt@gem_reloc_overflow@single-overflow": {
        "__type__": "TestResult",
        "command": "/home/gfx/intel-graphics/intel-gpu-tools/tests/gem_reloc_overflow --run-subtest single-overflow",
        "dmesg": "",
        "environment": "PIGLIT_PLATFORM=\"mixed_glx_egl\" PIGLIT_SOURCE_DIR=\"/home/gfx/intel-graphics/intel-gpu-tools/piglit\"",
        "err": "(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function reloc_tests, file gem_reloc_overflow.c:260:\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Failed assertion: __gem_execbuf(fd, &execbuf) == -14\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: error: -22 != -14\nSubtest single-overflow failed.\n**** DEBUG ****\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) DEBUG: relocation_count=4294967295\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function reloc_tests, file gem_reloc_overflow.c:260:\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: Failed assertion: __gem_execbuf(fd, &execbuf) == -14\n(gem_reloc_overflow:19562) CRITICAL: error: -22 != -14\n****  END  ****\n",
        "exception": null,
        "out": "IGT-Version: 1.14-g1e9a3ac (x86_64) (Linux: 4.6.0-rc4-drm-intel-nightly-ww17-commit-1e81bac+ x86_64)\nStack trace:\n  #0 [__igt_fail_assert+0x101]\n  #1 [reloc_tests+0x6d6]\n  #2 [<unknown>+0x6d6]\nSubtest single-overflow: FAIL (8.469s)\n",
        "pid": 19562,
        "result": "fail",
        "returncode": 99,
        "subtests": {
            "__type__": "Subtests"
        },
        "time": {
            "__type__": "TimeAttribute",
            "end": 1462072402.5360818,
            "start": 1462072393.7328644
        },
        "traceback": null
    }
}
```

The value that I need is "result : fail".

So far I have this code:

```
import json

with open("9.json") as json_file:
json_data = json.load(json_file)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract single value from JSON response Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/extract-single-value-from-json-response-python)

Comment: Why does this question carry the linux tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot!

```
for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
    result = value['result']

print result
```

UPDATE (for question in comments):
If you have multiple files and want to store all of the info at once - try throwing it all into a dictionary. This can vary depending on what you want the key to be. But try this (this will create a dicitonary of `{json_key: result_value}`:

```
all_results = {}
json_file_list = ['file_1.json', 'file_2.json']
for file in json_file_list:
    with open(file) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
            if 'result' in value:
                all_results[key] = value['result']
return all_results
```

Comment: thanks it works for me, i dont know if i can ask for one thing more, but if it is possible is there some way to improved this script, i mean i have 100 jsons in a folder, each one with different result, it is possible iterate on them and storage their differents results in several variables ? the results will be : fail, pass, dmesg-warn, dmesg-fail, skip, incomplete. if it is not possible i wll understand thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `json.load` function returns a dictionary (an object of type `dict`).

A dictionary associates keys with vlues. To access values inside the dictionary, you can use this syntax:

```
value = dictionary[key]
```

In your particular case:

```
result = json_data['result']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_data["igt@gem_reloc_overflow@single-overflow"]["result"]
```

this will print result

Comment: Why? Could you please add some context to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The json data is stored as a python dictionary.

Hence you can access the value of "result" as follows:

```
json_data["igt@gem_reloc_overflow@single-overflow"]["result"]
```

W.R.T your code:

```
import json

with open("9.json") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)


print(json_data["igt@gem_reloc_overflow@single-overflow"]["result"])
```