# Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'data' while trying to read one value in json (python)

Tags: python, json

I am getting an error while attempting to read one value from a json. The response from "https://status.mojang.com/check" is a list, which I then attempt to use only one element of. This gives me the `Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'data'` error.

## My code

```
    url = "https://status.mojang.com/check"
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    MinecraftNet = json_data[0]
    Accounts = json_data[3]
    Auth = json_data[4]
    Skins = json_data[5]
    Sessions = json_data[7]
    API = json_data[8]


    MinecraftNet = MinecraftNet["data"]["minecraft.net"]
    Accounts = Accounts["data"]["account.mojang.com"]
    Auth = Auth["data"]["auth.mojang.com"]
    Skins = Skins["data"]["skins.minecraft.net"]
    Sessions = Sessions["data"]["sessionserver.mojang.com"]
    API = API["data"]["{'api.mojang.com':'"]
    print(MinecraftNet, Accounts, Auth, Skins, Sessions, API)
```

Comment: Looks like the object MineCraftNet hasn't a field call "data". Could you print the json sgring received from the get request?

Comment: If you look at the json data you'll notice that it doesn't have a "data" key, and that "minecraft.net" is at the root level of the data. Try `MinecraftNet["minecraft.net"]`.

Comment: There appear to be multiple typos in the code, or at least the code doesn't match the data structure. It's possible that this should be a duplicate of either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193502/how-can-i-access-the-nested-data-in-this-complex-json-which-includes-another-js (that `"{'api.mojang.com':'"` key looks suspicious), but there's no way to answer the question properly without an [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing

```
MinecraftNet = json_data[0]
```

your `MinecraftNet` object contains

```
{
    minecraft.net: "green"
}
```

so the next call

```
MinecraftNet = MinecraftNet["data"]
```

is wrong.

Change it to

```
MinecraftNet = MinecraftNet["minecraft.net"]
```