# Handling keys inside a key from .json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to print an specific key from a JSON file without success.

.json file is:

```
{
    "testing": [
        {
            "_name": "teste",
            "_profile_telphone": "212331233",
            "_age": "21"
        }
    ]
}
```

the function I'm using is:

```
def load(self):
    filename = self.profile_entry.get()
    if filename == "":
        msg = "Insert a profile name"
        messagebox.showinfo("Profile name is empty", msg)
        self.profile_entry.focus()
    else:
        with open('profile_'+filename+'.json', 'r') as outfile:
            data = json.load(outfile)
            print(data[filename])
            outfile.close()
```

with `print(data[filename])` I can print entire

```
{
            "_name": "teste",
            "_profile_telphone": "212331233",
            "_age": "21"
        }
```

But how can I print only name or age for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a single value from JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: @buran as you can see this are inside another key. First key is 'testing' get by [filename] print(data[filename]) inside it we have _name

tried 
print(data[filename]['_name']) without sucess

Comment: Note that what you show as result of `print(data[filename])` is not correct. It will return a list with a dict inside it. You have dict inside list inside dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data is a list of JSONs - you have a json array there, in order to parse it you can do it with a for statement

```
for element in data[filename]:
    print(element[‘_name’])
    print(element[‘_profile_telphone’])
    print(element[‘_age’])
```

Comment: Thanks @Alin Stelian

Thats what i was looking for. this array thanks!!!