# How do I extract only the key from a Google Cloud Datastore entity

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a project using the gcloud cli tools. I am using Python + Flask for developing the application. My main reference points have been the [Google Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity) as well [this How-to tutorial guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app).

I have some entities in my Datastore and these entities have some properties. Entities are created in the application, with the Key set to the default Key (a.k.a incomplete key).

I am able to access the entities alright. And using projection, I can also access the properties of each entity. However, is there a way to only extract the Key from an entity? Example:

```py
>>> print(list(user_query.fetch()))
[<Entity('User', 5097358505279488) {...}>]
```

This works alright when I want to access the properties. However, I cannot access the key `509..`. I have also tried:

```py
>>> for user in user_query.fetch():
       print(user.key)
       ...
>>> <Key('User', 5097358505279488), project=...>
```

While it returns the whole Key object, I couldn't find a way to extract only the key. I have scoured the documentation for a solution, but it hasn't returned anything so. I am wondering if this is even possible at this point.

Comment: The docs imply that [Keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#key) are JSON objects.  Can you access the individual keyValue element using the [typical method of working with JSON objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response)?

Comment: @Frodnar That does not work unfortunately :( It throws the following error: `TypeError: Object of type Key is not JSON serializable`. I don't think the Key is stored in a way like the rest of the properties are.

Comment: Hate to send you down another rabbit hole when clearly I don't understand this issue myself, but could it be stored as a [protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)...?

Comment: @Frodnar I don't think that is possible as the Datastore API does not allow that. But I appreciate the help none the less.

Answer (score 2):

You use this to get id

```
print(user.key.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to get a projection of key.id.  Unfortunately, this is not possible.  You can do a [keys-only](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) query that returns the [keys](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/keys.html), then you can use a list comprehension to get the data you want, e.g. `[key.id_or_name for key in key_only_query.fetch_page()]`

Comment: While the solution isn't exactly as you outlined, I was eventually able to come up with the solution I needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the .id property on a datastore entity to get the key as an integer value.

`for user in user_query.fetch():`

`print(user.id)`