# How to get a particular key value inside dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
{
    "id": "3xj1z9mKjaI",
    "title": "\u0d36\u0d3e\u0d2a \u0d35\u0d3e\u0d15\u0d4d\u0d15\u0d4d \u0d2a\u0d31\u0d1e\u0d4d\u0d1e\u0d3f\u0d1f\u0d4d\u0d1f\u0d41\u0d33\u0d4d\u0d33 \u0d09\u0d2e\u0d4d\u0d2e\u0d2e\u0d3e\u0d30\u0d4d\u200d \u0d05\u0d31\u0d3f\u0d2f\u0d23\u0d02 | \u0d15\u0d30\u0d1e\u0d4d\u0d1e\u0d4d \u0d2a\u0d4b\u0d15\u0d41\u0d02 | makkal mathapithakkal | marhaba media",
    "viewCount": {
        "text": "163509"
    }
}
```

Give a solution to get the value corresponding to ''text'' key

Comment: `d['viewCount']['text']`

Comment: ```whatever_dict['viewCount']['text']```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a single value from JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a specific value in a dict by using the subscript operator (`[]`). If the value that keys refers to is a dict itself, you can continue using the subscript operator on it. In your case:

```py
text_value = my_dict['viewCount']['text']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[]` operator.

By using it on the dictionary, it will return the value attached to that key, the same way a method would do so. This means that you can get the returned value and put it inside a variable, use it in a method, etc...

Example :

```py
dct = {
    "my_first_key": "my_first_value",
    "my_second_key": "my_second_value"
}

my_var = dct["my_first_key"] # This variable will contain the string : "my_first_value"
```

You can then replicate this for an "inside dictionary" :

```py
dct = {
    "my_first_key": "my_first_value",
    "my_second_key": "my_second_value",
    "my_second_dict": {
        "my_third_key": "my_third_value"
    }
}

my_var = dct["my_first_key"] # This variable will contain the string : "my_first_value"

my_final_var = dct["my_second_dict"]["my_third_key"] # This variable will contain the string : "my_third_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at the official [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), for your question the working code would be:

```
print(name_of_your_dictionary['viewCount']['text'])
```