# Pulling data from JSON in Python: error - "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, json

I'm seeking to pull specific data from a JSONs captured by an API pull. There's no problem in getting the entire JSON, but I'm experiencing problems trying to pull specific data from the JSON.

The JSON is a series of 20 data entries structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "body": "string",
    "grade": "100",
    "user_id": 5531,
  },

]
```

Here's my attempt to pull data:

```
import requests
import json

url = API url
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer API key'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_data = r.json()
print(json_data["user_id"])
```

Which generates the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Clearly I'm missing something - any thoughts? All assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the json_data variable is a list. In which case, you will have to loop and extract out the list of user_ids like so. Please check the output of json_data to confirm if I am correct or not?

Comment: Can confirm - json data is in a list.

Comment: So you want to extract all user_ids, loop through it and append in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this should work for you:

```
user_id_list = []
for data in json_data:
    user_id_list.append(data['user_id'])
print(user_id_list)
```

You can even return the user_id_list in the last line if it is in a function, as required.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using a python dictionary not a list. Use `json.loads()`. This answer here: [How to extract a single value from JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response) should help.