# get name of "product" from json

Tags: python, json

this is JSON text, I want to get name of "product":

```
{"result": "success", "totalresults": 1, "startnumber": 0, "numreturned": 1, "orders": {"order": [{"id": 3267, "ordernum": 13424555, "userid": 2132, "contactid": 0, "requestor_id": 2173, "admin_requestor_id": 0, "date": "2022-08-05 16:39:18", "nameservers": "", "transfersecret": "", "renewals": "", "promocode": "", "promotype": "", "promovalue": "", "orderdata": "[]", "amount": "12.00", "paymentmethod": "usd", "invoiceid": 101, "status": "Active", "ipaddress": "111.111.111.111", "fraudmodule": "", "fraudoutput": "", "notes": "", "paymentmethodname": "Cryptocurrencies", "paymentstatus": "Paid", "name": "Max Vorenberg", "currencyprefix": "$", "currencysuffix": " USD", "frauddata": "", "validationdata": "", "lineitems": {"lineitem": [{"type": "product", "relid": 3648, "producttype": "Dedicated/VPS Server", "product": "Dedicated Server Windows", "domain": "chz", "billingcycle": "Monthly", "amount": "$12.00 USD", "status": "Active"}]}}]}}
```

this is my code:

```
     data = {
            'identifier':identifier,
            'secret':secret, 
            'action': 'GetOrders',
            'id':3267,
            'responsetype':'json',
            } 
    # sending post request and saving response as response object 
    r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 
    data2 = r.json()
    text_data2 = json.dumps(data2)
    print(text_data2)
    print(text_data2['product'])
```

but get the error : `"NameError: name 'string' is not defined"`

Comment: Without context it seems this will work: `data["orders"]["order"][0]["lineitems"]["lineitem"][0]["product"]`

Comment: Sorry, exact output i want is : "Dedicated Server Windows"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get you your expected result for your example input:

```
data["orders"]["order"][0]["lineitems"]["lineitem"][0]["product"]
```

Although, where I have `[0]` it is getting the first item in those lists. Your example has only one item in the lists but if there are more, you will need to iterate over them to get the result(s) you want.

This is based on your example data:

```
data = {
     'numreturned': 1,
     'orders': {'order': [{'admin_requestor_id': 0,
                           'amount': '12.00',
                           'contactid': 0,
                           'currencyprefix': '$',
                           'currencysuffix': ' USD',
                           'date': '2022-08-05 16:39:18',
                           'frauddata': '',
                           'fraudmodule': '',
                           'fraudoutput': '',
                           'id': 3267,
                           'invoiceid': 101,
                           'ipaddress': '111.111.111.111',
                           'lineitems': {'lineitem': [{'amount': '$12.00 USD',
                                                       'billingcycle': 'Monthly',
                                                       'domain': 'chz',
                                                       'product': 'Dedicated '
                                                                  'Server Windows',
                                                       'producttype': 'Dedicated/VPS '
                                                                      'Server',
                                                       'relid': 3648,
                                                       'status': 'Active',
                                                       'type': 'product'}]},
                           'name': 'Max Vorenberg',
                           'nameservers': '',
                           'notes': '',
                           'orderdata': '[]',
                           'ordernum': 13424555,
                           'paymentmethod': 'usd',
                           'paymentmethodname': 'Cryptocurrencies',
                           'paymentstatus': 'Paid',
                           'promocode': '',
                           'promotype': '',
                           'promovalue': '',
                           'renewals': '',
                           'requestor_id': 2173,
                           'status': 'Active',
                           'transfersecret': '',
                           'userid': 2132,
                           'validationdata': ''}]},
     'result': 'success',
     'startnumber': 0,
     'totalresults': 1
}
```

## Explanation

To break this down I am first getting `data["orders]` which contains this dictionary:

```
{
 'order': [{'admin_requestor_id': 0,
            ...
            'lineitems': {'lineitem': [{'amount': '$12.00 USD',
                                        'billingcycle': 'Monthly',
                                        'domain': 'chz',
                                        'product': 'Dedicated Server Windows',
                                        'producttype': 'Dedicated/VPS Server',
                                        'relid': 3648,
                                        'status': 'Active',
                                        'type': 'product'}]},
            ...
    ]
}
```

This dictionary only has one key "orders", which contains a list containing a single dictionary. If you expect it to have more than one dictionary in it then you will need to loop through it like so:

```
for order in data["orders"]["order"]:
    ...
```

In the `...` you would have a single order like the following:

```
{
     'admin_requestor_id': 0,
     ...
     'lineitems': {'lineitem': [{'amount': '$12.00 USD',
                                 'billingcycle': 'Monthly',
                                 'domain': 'chz',
                                 'product': 'Dedicated Server Windows',
                                 'producttype': 'Dedicated/VPS Server',
                                 'relid': 3648,
                                 'status': 'Active',
                                 'type': 'product'}]},
     ...
    }
```

This has a key "lineitems" which is a dictionary containing a single key "lineitem" which is another list of dictionaries and like above you can iterate this as well. Our code thus far would become:

```
for order in data["orders"]["order"]:
    for item in order["lineitems"]["lineitem"]:
        ...
```

Now in the inner loop we have a dictionary like the following:

```
{
    'amount': '$12.00 USD',
    'billingcycle': 'Monthly',
    'domain': 'chz',
    'product': 'Dedicated Server Windows',
    'producttype': 'Dedicated/VPS Server',
    'relid': 3648,
    'status': 'Active',
    'type': 'product'
}
```

This dictionary has the key "product" which is the value we are looking for. Our iterative approach now becomes:

```
for order in data["orders"]["order"]:
    for item in order["lineitems"]["lineitem"]:
        print(item["product"])
```

Comment: This is the answer but based on the original question I have to assume they don't understand WHY you have to call all these things. Does someone have a good link that describes how to looks at JSON values via python?

Comment: @Wumbo The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-can-i-extract-a-single-value-from-a-json-response) has a good brief explanation.

Comment: @Wumbo Added a detailed explanation

Comment: very easy to understand, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to see why, when the json is formatted visually:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "totalresults": 1,
    "startnumber": 0,
    "numreturned": 1,
    "orders": {
        "order": [
            {
                "id": 3267,
                "ordernum": 13424555,
                "userid": 2132,
                "contactid": 0,
                "requestor_id": 2173,
                "admin_requestor_id": 0,
                "date": "2022-08-05 16:39:18",
                "nameservers": "",
                "transfersecret": "",
                "renewals": "",
                "promocode": "",
                "promotype": "",
                "promovalue": "",
                "orderdata": "[]",
                "amount": "12.00",
                "paymentmethod": "usd",
                "invoiceid": 101,
                "status": "Active",
                "ipaddress": "111.111.111.111",
                "fraudmodule": "",
                "fraudoutput": "",
                "notes": "",
                "paymentmethodname": "Cryptocurrencies",
                "paymentstatus": "Paid",
                "name": "Max Vorenberg",
                "currencyprefix": "$",
                "currencysuffix": " USD",
                "frauddata": "",
                "validationdata": "",
                "lineitems": {
                    "lineitem": [
                        {
                            "type": "product",
                            "relid": 3648,
                            "producttype": "Dedicated/VPS Server",
                            "product": "Dedicated Server Windows",
                            "domain": "chz",
                            "billingcycle": "Monthly",
                            "amount": "$12.00 USD",
                            "status": "Active"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The product value that you are looking for is nested under a collection of objects and arrays, so you'll need a more sophisticated approach to parsing the value out.

At its simplest, you could access it via `data2["orders"]["order"][0]["lineitems"]["lineitem"][0]["product"]`, but this assumes that all the objects and arrays are present, that they contain values, and the first item in each array is the one you want. Nothing to go wrong there. ;)

Also, you may want to add in some try blocks around the request etc, as if they fail they'll throw an exception.