# Get the highest value of a specific field from an API reponse in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I make a GET to a API

I got this back

```
{"status":200,"message":"Success","data":[{"email_address":"admin@nyunets.com","password":"admin","account_id":1000,"account_type":"admin","name_prefix":null,"first_name":null,"middle_names":null,"last_name":"Admin","name_suffix":null,"non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"Admin","address1":"111 Park Ave","address2":"Floor 4","address3":"Suite 4011","city":"New York","state":"NY","postal_code":"10022","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"212-555-1212","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":2,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1446127072},{"email_address":"mhn@nyu.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":1002,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"MHN","middle_names":"","last_name":"User","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"MHNUser","address1":"3101 Knox St","address2":"","address3":"","city":"Dallas","state":"TX","postal_code":"75205","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"8623875097","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":2,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1461166172},{"email_address":"mhn1@nyu.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":1004,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"MHN1","middle_names":"","last_name":"User","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"MHN1User","address1":"1010 Rosedale Shopping Center","address2":"","address3":"","city":"Roseville","state":"MN","postal_code":"55113","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"8279856982","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":2,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1461166417},{"email_address":"location@nyu.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":1005,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"BB","middle_names":"","last_name":"HH","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"BBHH","address1":"9906 Beverly Dr","address2":"9906 Beverly Dr","address3":"","city":"Beverly Hills","state":"CA","postal_code":"90210","nation_code":"90210","phone1":"3105559906","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":1,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1461167224},{"email_address":"mbn1@nyu.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":1003,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"MBN1","middle_names":"","last_name":"User","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"MBN1User","address1":"3200 S Las Vegas Blvd","address2":"","address3":"","city":"Las Vegas","state":"NV","postal_code":"89109","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"9273597497","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":1,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1461593233},{"email_address":"mbn@nyu.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":1001,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"MBN","middle_names":"","last_name":"User","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"MBNUser","address1":"300 Concord Road","address2":"","address3":"","city":"Billerica","state":"MA","postal_code":"01821","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"8127085695","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":1,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1461784499},{"email_address":"usermbn@nyu.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":1006,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"User","middle_names":"","last_name":"MBN","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"UserMBN","address1":"75 Saint Alphonsus Street","address2":"","address3":"","city":"Boston","state":"MA","postal_code":"01821","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"8127085695","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":1,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1462285561},{"email_address":"emile.barnaby@example.com","password":"nyu123","account_id":2000,"account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"emile","middle_names":"","last_name":"barnaby","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"dba":"","display_name":"emilebarnaby","address1":"300 Concord Rd","address2":"","address3":"","city":"8239grandmaraisave","state":"manitoba","postal_code":"56798","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"414-140-1435","phone2":"414-140-1435","phone3":"414-140-1435","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":1,"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1462211572}]}
```

---

## I have

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://api/users"
accounts = requests.get(url).json()
data = json.loads(accounts)

object_with_max_account_id = max(accounts['data'], key=lambda x: x['account_id'])
print(object_with_max_account_id['account_id'])
```

---

## Goal

is to get the **highest** account id out of it.

Comment: What is this? How is your data stored? Are you using something built-in or a lib like numpy?

Comment: It's a sample response from an API call.

Comment: Next time, work a bit harder and search around a bit before asking on SO, and include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's very frustrating to spend time answering a question only to have that question change so much that later readers find the answer doesn't address the later question (maybe to the point where it has to be deleted) when it *did* address the original.  [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we like to see what OPs try themselves, this is pretty much straightforward.

```
import requests

url = "http://api/users"
accounts = requests.get(url).json()

object_with_max_account_id = max(accounts['data'], key=lambda x: x['account_id'])
print(object_with_max_account_id['account_id'])
>>  2000
```

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'account_id'`

Comment: Can you please help ? I'll update my post with what I have with your code.

Comment: It means the API you are using is returning a list of strings. You will have to turn it to a list of objects. We can't help you much farther without knowing what kind of API it is

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: I saw. Thanks for your trying to help :)

Comment: I got this `TypeError: expected string or buffer`.

Comment: On which line? That exact code works for me with the new `data` you provided

Comment: Wait, you removed the `json.loads(accounts)` ?

Comment: @ihue Ok, so `.json()` already does the parsing for you. So you don't actually need the line `data = json.loads(accounts)`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Ahh.. Okay. I got it now. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112191/discussion-between-ihue-and-deepspace).

Comment: What is this do `key=lambda x: x['account_id']` ?

Comment: It's letting the `max` function know that you are looking for the element with the maximum `account_id`.

Comment: Thank-you mate, you save my life. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Apparently, you first need to [parse your input as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python).
Check out [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson).

```
import simplejson as json
data_obj = json.loads(data)
```

*The s in loads means load from string.*
Then, if you want to be looping through, how about something like:

```
maxID= -1
for account in data_obj:
    if(account[account_id])>maxID:
        maxID= account[account_id]
print "Max ID is %d" % maxID
```

Comment: @ihue Updated. Does that help?

Comment: I got this `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: What is the result of `type(accounts)`?

Comment: `print type(accounts)` --> `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: Look like I already got my answer. But +1 for trying to help. :)

Comment: After you made the changes such that accounts is now a dictionary, did you try the second bit of code again as-is?  You've been very rapidly changing what you are requesting here and establishing as preconditions.

Comment: So then are you going to stick with 'looping through' as originally requested, or are you going with the max() function as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: Your looping through is not working, and require me to install more things. which the other answer is not.

Comment: It doesn't need anything new to be installed once you so significantly changed the question to have the input data already parsed as JSON.  `simplejson` reportedly has better performance than the default `json` so it's an option for you, if you care about that.