# How to read dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I have a file of name "input.txt". In this text file a lot of dictionaries are stored. I have to iterate through these dictionaries. How do read the file? Whenever I read the file using open(), file.read() it coverts the whole text into a string type. How to read this file as collection of dictionaries?

Contents of input.txt:

```
{"label":18,"words":["realclearpolitics","-","election","2016","-","2016","republican","presidential","nomination","polls","year","state"]}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far?

Comment: There is a missing `]` before the ending `}`

Comment: Rolled back your question before it's closed for asking several unrelated questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `json` module's method to convert loaded `str` to `dict` for each line in the file:

```
import json

with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line_as_dict = json.loads(line)
        # process here the dict
```

Comment: Suppose my dictionary is {"words" : ['q', 'a', 'asa'], "values":[1,45,3]}. How do  I print (word,value)?

Comment: @arihant34, first you read it in as a dictionary, then you read up on how to use dictionaries (which is an entirely different question from what you've asked here.)

Comment: This solution will only work if each line is a complete json object (or if the file has no newlines at all). Why hobble your code this way?

Comment: Actually I dealing with big data, the file here is obtained from performing tf-idf on text.  The file is in the format of many lines where each line is a dictionary , representing a file. This dictionary consists of  words and values . I wanted to map each word to its value.

Comment: In that case, @Gabor's solution is exactly right, and in fact necessary. (A json file can only contain one top-level object.) But to deal with big data, you should be using a saner / more compact format to dump your data.

Comment: Spark supports json and paraquet.

Comment: If you have a lot of the same data and they can have the same values you could consider using the `__slots__` class member as this will decrease the memory footprint of your big data. However there could be a better solution using another module that is dealing with big data, like the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

the closing list bracket was missing in the string. You can use code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771071/1150303) - with the existing json module of python:

```
import json

x = '{"label":18,"words":["realclearpolitics","-","election","2016","-","2016","republican","presidential","nomination","polls","year","state"]}'
j = json.loads(x)
print(j)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the contents of a line are a well-formed dict, you can use `eval` to execute the string in python

```
line = {"label":18,"words":["realclearpolitics","-","election","2016","-","2016","republican","presidential","nomination","polls","year","state"]}
dictionary = eval(line)
print(dictionary)
```

So if you have only that one line in input, you can use

```
dictionary = eval(open("input.txt").read())
```

or if you have one dictionary per line

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         dictionary = eval(line)
```

Comment: EVAL IS EVIL .. :D

Comment: well, use at your own risk! just pointing out it's possible. it can be a valid quick and dirty solution if you're sure what you're evaluating.

Comment: I have many dictionaries in the form of a lines.

Comment: Never use eval where [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will do. And json isn't quite Python literals.

Comment: @IronFist:  eval is a tool. Like any tool, it can be used for good or evil.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```
import ast
import json

def readfile():
    f = open(path_to_file, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    data = ast.literal_eval(content)
    print(json.loads(data))
```

ast.literal_eval raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not. So, the content that is being read from file gets validated as well

**Output:**

```
{'label': 18,
 'words': ['realclearpolitics',
  '-',
  'election',
  '2016',
  '-',
  '2016',
  'republican',
  'presidential',
  'nomination',
  'polls',
  'year',
  'state']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect, you missed to close the array, however the corrected JSON is below:

```
{
    "label": 18,
    "words": ["realclearpolitics", "-", "election", "2016", "-", "2016", "republican", "presidential", "nomination", "polls", "year", "state"]
}
```

You can use `json` built-in function `load` to read a JSON file:

```
import json
with open(r'path\of\your\file') as data_file:
    jsonData = json.load(data_file)
    print jsonData # it will print whole JSON data
    print jsonData['words'] # it will print value of the key `word`
```