# Python - How to convert JSON File to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How can I  convert a JSON File as such  into a dataframe to do some transformations.

For Example if the JSON file reads:

```
{"FirstName":"John",

"LastName":"Mark",

"MiddleName":"Lewis",

"username":"johnlewis2",

"password":"2910"}
```

How can I convert it to a table like such

```
Column -> FirstName | LastName | MiddleName | username | password



Row ----->    John | Mark |Lewis | johnlewis2 |2910
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Creating dataframe from dictionary object.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'name': 'vikash', 'age': 27}, {'name': 'Satyam', 'age': 14}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')

df
Out[4]:
   age  name
0   27  vikash
1   14  Satyam
```

If you have nested columns then you first need to normalize the data:

```
data = [
  {
    'name': {
      'first': 'vikash',
      'last': 'singh'
    },
    'age': 27
  },
  {
    'name': {
      'first': 'satyam',
      'last': 'singh'
    },
    'age': 14
  }
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(data), orient='columns')

df    
Out[8]:
age name.first  name.last
0   27  vikash  singh
1   14  satyam  singh
```

Source:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)
- [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Answer (score 11):

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.json_normalize(your_json))
```

This will Normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table

**Output**

```
  FirstName LastName MiddleName password    username
      John     Mark      Lewis     2910  johnlewis2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marlon Abeykoon, very useful especially if I want to import a JSON

Comment: Glad that it helped you

Answer (score 4):

```
jsondata = '{"0001":{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Mark","MiddleName":"Lewis","username":"johnlewis2","password":"2910"}}'
import json
import pandas as pd
jdata = json.loads(jsondata)
df = pd.DataFrame(jdata)
print df.T
```

This should look like this:.

```
         FirstName LastName MiddleName password    username
0001      John     Mark      Lewis     2910  johnlewis2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 inputs you might have and you can also convert between them.

1. input: listOfDictionaries --> use @VikashSingh solution

example: `[{"":{"...`

*The pd.DataFrame() needs a listOfDictionaries as input.*

2. input: jsonStr --> use @JustinMalinchak solution

example: `'{"":{"...`

If you have jsonStr, you need an extra step to listOfDictionaries first. This is obvious as it is generated like:

```
jsonStr = json.dumps(listOfDictionaries)
```

Thus, switch back from jsonStr to listOfDictionaries first:

```
listOfDictionaries = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this where file1.json is the file name can read the json files directly from the json file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("file1.json")
```