# How to convert the below json data to dataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "mgch_7": {
    "plot": {
      "ra": {
        [
          1547551080000,
          24
        ],
        [
          1547551140000,
          24
        ],
        [
          1547551200000,
          24
        ],
        [
          1547551260000,
          24
        ]
      ]
    },
    "user": {},
    "maintainance": {}
  }
}
```

In the DataFrame I want two columns, e.g.: 1547551080000 in one column and 24 in second column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to convert JSON File to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168558/python-how-to-convert-json-file-to-dataframe)

Comment: I can't figure it out please help

Comment: that's not the same problem :)

Comment: That JSON is not valid. I believe you have an extra ] in there

Comment: Also, that "set" of lists of pairs of values that you want to be converted should be a list of dictionaries in order for this to be a valid JSON (e.g., [{1547551080000 : 24}, {1547551140000, 24}], or [{'Val1': 1547551080000, 'Val2': 24}, {'Val1': 1547551140000, 'Val2': 24}]).

Comment: Here is valid json close to above. `{ "mgch_7": { "plot": { "ra": { "a": [1547551080000, 24], "b": [1547551140000, 24], "c": [1547551200000, 24], "d": [1547551260000, 24] }, "user": {}, "maintainance": {} } } }`