# Determine whether json is Geojson

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have several fields in a json file, and I need to determine which of the json-fields are GeoJSON. For example, here is a sample of the data I have:

```
{
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 20,
    "info": {"height": 189, "weight": 101}
    "location": { "type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]},"properties": {"name": "Dinagat Islands"}}
}
```

I would like to get the following column information from this:

- name (string)
- age (int)
- info (json)
- location (geojson)

What would be the best way to determine if a json object is actually a GeoJSON object? I've viewed various examples of GeoJSON, such as http://geojsonlint.com/ and it seems like it is quite flexible in how it can be specified.

Is there a sure-fire way to know whether a json object is GeoJSON or not?

Comment: Give it to a geojson parser?

Comment: @Goyo for example?

Comment: Did your research not yield any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas to convert the json/geojson object into a dataframe. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168558/python-how-to-convert-json-file-to-dataframe/41168691).
Get location points using:

Install [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/).

`pip install geopy`

To get the location:

`location = df['location']['geometry']['coordinates']`

Then,

```
try:
   from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
   geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
   location = geolocator.reverse(str(location))
   print(location.address)
except:
   print('not GEOjson') #there will be exception if the coordinates don't represent a location
```

This based on the fact that `coordinates` are a `pair` and will give a location address.

**Else:**

You can just check if they have some features like `coordinates` or `geometry` then its `geojson`.

As the whole thing is in a dataframe, then it is easier to visualise and to use any value as you wish!!

You can also get `name`, `location` or anything else in the same way.