# how to convert a json file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a JSON file which is like this

```
{'work':'12234','product':'mobile','rating':'3'}
{'work':'12444','product':'mobile','rating':'4'}              
{'work':'12634','product':'tv','rating':'5'}
{'work':'12277','product':'ac','rating':'3'}
```

and so on

I want to convert it into a `dataframe` can anyone help me with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No it did not, that is a list of dictionaries, my file is as shown above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to convert JSON File to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168558/python-how-to-convert-json-file-to-dataframe)

Comment: Your file is not JSON. JSON expects property names to be enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not JSON. JSON expects property names to be enclosed in double quotes.  But, you can work around it.

```
import pandas as pd 

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = [eval(line) for line in f]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: can you please explain this code

Comment: The code reads your text file line by line and converts it to a list of dictionary using eval and list comprehension. Your line is a string of python dictionary. Eval will change it to a dictionary.