# how to read json.txt and parse json python READ TXT PYTHON

Tags: python, json

I have one txt file:  resultJSON.txt

the data in the txt file is in JSON format.

```
{
    "term": "dog",
    "results": [{
        "filename": "1.jpg",
        "numberID": "D12"
    }, {
        "filename": "23.jpg",
        "number": "E52"
    }]
}
```

I would like to read the txt into python and parse the JSON.

How to read the txt???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Comment: OH PLEASE, IT IS READ TXT ,not duplicated

Comment: Also, if your .txt is in JSON format, you should rename it ".json".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure the following code is in the same folder as `resultJSON.txt`:

```
import json
with open('resultJSON.txt') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```

Your data will be in `json_data`.