# how to extract certain keywords from a text file using Python

Tags: python

i want to extract a certain keyword called "Visual Impairment" from a huge text file. i know this is probably a very minor issue but i am still fairly new to Python so please help :)

an example of the text file:
{'Sensory and Communication': {'Visual Impairment': 'No', 'Hearing Impairment': 'YesMild', 'Communication': 'YesVerbal'}

i want it to be such that 'No = 0' and the output to be

```
Visual Impairment: 0
```

my code now is

```
file_path ='C:\\Users\L31308\Desktop\\IFA.txt'

with open(file_path,'r') as f:

data = f.read()



def sensoryAndCommunication(visualImpairment, hearingImpairment, communication):

   if visualImpairment == 'Visual Impairment':

       if visualImpairment == 'No':

           visualImpairment = 0

           print("Visual Impairment" + visualImpairment)
```

Comment: There's an indentation error in your `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit all over the place. Besides the indentation problem stated before in the comment, your function does not make much sense. You are checking `if visualImpairment == 'Visual Impairment':` and then right after you are checking `if visualImpairment == 'No':` There is no way a variable can have two different values. Besides that, you are not even using the data you read to extract information from. It seems like you are a little confused about the way it needs to be done.

1- It appears that the file you are reading is written in a JSON format, if that is the case, I think you should try parsing the text to extract the information you are looking for. Try this [Link for a start](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/json/) or look for other tutorials

2- Once you learn how to parse correctly, use that to extract the information you are looking for and then use an if-condition to check if the value is 'Yes' or 'No'.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you are trying to read json object from text file. if that is the case then your json objects in 'IFA.txt'should be formatted as follows:

```
{"Sensory and Communication":{"Visual Impairment":"No","Hearing Impairment":"YesMild","Communication":"YesVerbal"}}
```

note the double-quotes.then it will be easy to parse the file. follow this [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631873/how-to-read-json-txt-and-parse-json-python-read-txt-python) so that you will have clear picture .try the following code:

```
import json
with open('IFA.txt') as f:
   json_data = json.load(f)
   # in python single-quote and double-quote makes no difference
   if  json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Visual Impairment']=='No':
       print json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Visual Impairment']
```