# How to get a particular value from the given json

Tags: python, json

I have the following json

```
`{
    "count": 4,
    "node": [{
        "assetRecord": {
            "additionalhardware": null,
            "admin": null,
            "assetNumber": null,
            "autoenable": null,
            "building": null,
            "category": "Unspecified",
            "circuitId": null,
            "comment": null,
            "connection": null,
            "cpu": null,
            "dateInstalled": null,
            "department": null,
            "description": null,
            "displayCategory": null,
            "division": null,
            "enable": null,
            "floor": null,
            "hdd1": null,
            "hdd2": null,
            "hdd3": null,
            "hdd4": null,
            "hdd5": null,
            "hdd6": null,
            "id": 10817,
            "inputpower": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": "",
            "lastModifiedDate": 1491855810758,
            "lease": null,
            "leaseExpires": null,
            "maintContractExpiration": null,
            "maintContractNumber": null,
            "maintcontract": null,
            "managedObjectInstance": null,
            "managedObjectType": null,
            "manufacturer": null,
            "modelNumber": null,
            "notifyCategory": null,
            "numpowersupplies": null,
            "operatingSystem": null,
            "password": null,
            "pollerCategory": null,
            "port": null,
            "rack": null,
            "rackunitheight": null,
            "ram": null,
            "region": null,
            "room": null,
            "serialNumber": null,
            "slot": null,
            "snmpcommunity": null,
            "storagectrl": null,
            "supportPhone": null,
            "thresholdCategory": null,
            "username": null,
            "vendor": null,
            "vendorAssetNumber": null,
            "vendorFax": null,
            "vendorPhone": null,
            "vmwareManagedEntityType": null,
            "vmwareManagedObjectId": null,
            "vmwareManagementServer": null,
            "vmwareState": null,
            "vmwareTopologyInfo": null
        },
        "categories": [],
        "createTime": 1491855810758,
        "foreignId": null,
        "foreignSource": null,
        "id": "564",
        "label": "10.21.204.174",
        "labelSource": "A",
        "lastCapsdPoll": 1491855810984,
        "type": "A"
    }, {
        "assetRecord": {
            "additionalhardware": null,
            "admin": null,
            "assetNumber": null,
            "autoenable": null,
            "building": null,
            "category": "Unspecified",
            "circuitId": null,
            "comment": null,
            "connection": null,
            "cpu": null,
            "dateInstalled": null,
            "department": null,
            "description": null,
            "displayCategory": null,
            "division": null,
            "enable": null,
            "floor": null,
            "hdd1": null,
            "hdd2": null,
            "hdd3": null,
            "hdd4": null,
            "hdd5": null,
            "hdd6": null,
            "id": 10589,
            "inputpower": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": "",
            "lastModifiedDate": 1490819238331,
            "lease": null,
            "leaseExpires": null,
            "maintContractExpiration": null,
            "maintContractNumber": null,
            "maintcontract": null,
            "managedObjectInstance": null,
            "managedObjectType": null,
            "manufacturer": null,
            "modelNumber": null,
            "notifyCategory": null,
            "numpowersupplies": null,
            "operatingSystem": null,
            "password": null,
            "pollerCategory": null,
            "port": null,
            "rack": null,
            "rackunitheight": null,
            "ram": null,
            "region": null,
            "room": null,
            "serialNumber": null,
            "slot": null,
            "snmpcommunity": null,
            "storagectrl": null,
            "supportPhone": null,
            "thresholdCategory": null,
            "username": null,
            "vendor": null,
            "vendorAssetNumber": null,
            "vendorFax": null,
            "vendorPhone": null,
            "vmwareManagedEntityType": null,
            "vmwareManagedObjectId": null,
            "vmwareManagementServer": null,
            "vmwareState": null,
            "vmwareTopologyInfo": null
        },
        "categories": [],
        "createTime": 1490819238331,
        "foreignId": null,
        "foreignSource": null,
        "id": "561",
        "label": "10.21.205.148",
        "labelSource": "A",
        "lastCapsdPoll": 1490819238557,
        "type": "A"
    }, {
        "assetRecord": {
            "additionalhardware": null,
            "admin": null,
            "assetNumber": null,
            "autoenable": null,
            "building": null,
            "category": "Unspecified",
            "circuitId": null,
            "comment": null,
            "connection": null,
            "cpu": null,
            "dateInstalled": null,
            "department": null,
            "description": null,
            "displayCategory": null,
            "division": null,
            "enable": null,
            "floor": null,
            "hdd1": null,
            "hdd2": null,
            "hdd3": null,
            "hdd4": null,
            "hdd5": null,
            "hdd6": null,
            "id": 7554,
            "inputpower": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": "",
            "lastModifiedDate": 1477563144159,
            "lease": null,
            "leaseExpires": null,
            "maintContractExpiration": null,
            "maintContractNumber": null,
            "maintcontract": null,
            "managedObjectInstance": null,
            "managedObjectType": null,
            "manufacturer": null,
            "modelNumber": null,
            "notifyCategory": null,
            "numpowersupplies": null,
            "operatingSystem": null,
            "password": null,
            "pollerCategory": null,
            "port": null,
            "rack": null,
            "rackunitheight": null,
            "ram": null,
            "region": null,
            "room": null,
            "serialNumber": null,
            "slot": null,
            "snmpcommunity": null,
            "storagectrl": null,
            "supportPhone": null,
            "thresholdCategory": null,
            "username": null,
            "vendor": null,
            "vendorAssetNumber": null,
            "vendorFax": null,
            "vendorPhone": null,
            "vmwareManagedEntityType": null,
            "vmwareManagedObjectId": null,
            "vmwareManagementServer": null,
            "vmwareState": null,
            "vmwareTopologyInfo": null
        },
        "categories": [],
        "createTime": 1477563144159,
        "foreignId": null,
        "foreignSource": null,
        "id": "462",
        "label": "10.21.50.153",
        "labelSource": "A",
        "lastCapsdPoll": 1490722710498,
        "type": "A"
    }, {
        "assetRecord": {
            "additionalhardware": null,
            "admin": null,
            "assetNumber": null,
            "autoenable": null,
            "building": null,
            "category": "Unspecified",
            "circuitId": null,
            "comment": null,
            "connection": null,
            "cpu": null,
            "dateInstalled": null,
            "department": null,
            "description": null,
            "displayCategory": null,
            "division": null,
            "enable": null,
            "floor": null,
            "hdd1": null,
            "hdd2": null,
            "hdd3": null,
            "hdd4": null,
            "hdd5": null,
            "hdd6": null,
            "id": 5119,
            "inputpower": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": "",
            "lastModifiedDate": 1461419153008,
            "lease": null,
            "leaseExpires": null,
            "maintContractExpiration": null,
            "maintContractNumber": null,
            "maintcontract": null,
            "managedObjectInstance": null,
            "managedObjectType": null,
            "manufacturer": null,
            "modelNumber": null,
            "notifyCategory": null,
            "numpowersupplies": null,
            "operatingSystem": null,
            "password": null,
            "pollerCategory": null,
            "port": null,
            "rack": null,
            "rackunitheight": null,
            "ram": null,
            "region": null,
            "room": null,
            "serialNumber": null,
            "slot": null,
            "snmpcommunity": null,
            "storagectrl": null,
            "supportPhone": null,
            "thresholdCategory": null,
            "username": null,
            "vendor": null,
            "vendorAssetNumber": null,
            "vendorFax": null,
            "vendorPhone": null,
            "vmwareManagedEntityType": null,
            "vmwareManagedObjectId": null,
            "vmwareManagementServer": null,
            "vmwareState": null,
            "vmwareTopologyInfo": null
        },
        "categories": [],
        "createTime": 1461419153008,
        "foreignId": null,
        "foreignSource": null,
        "id": "389",
        "label": "dummyname_xv1",
        "labelSource": "A",
        "lastCapsdPoll": 1490722710502,
        "type": "A"
    }],
    "totalCount": 271
}
```

This above code is actually dumped in a file (say abc.txt) and it is a valid JSON format. I need to open the file and traverse to the "label" field.
I need to write a code which should extract/print the "label" value only if it is a IP i.e something in format of 0.0.0.0

How to do so ?

Comment: do you know how to access/traverse through a JS object? Try it out, the same way you need to do with your above problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `json` module to parse json file and iterate `node`:

[json.load()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)

> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a
>   JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

If you want to validate IP string is valid , you can use [inet_aton ()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton).

> Convert an IPv4 address from dotted-quad string format (for example,
>   ‘123.45.67.89’) to 32-bit packed binary format, as a string four
>   characters in length.

```
import json
import socket


for i in json.load(open('ooo.json'))["node"]:
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(i["label"])
        print(i["label"])
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Result:

```
10.21.204.174
10.21.205.148
10.21.50.153
```

Comment: what happens if 'hai.hello' in label??

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR I update my answer, add the part of validating IP.