# How to retrieve variables values from json using python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks as follows:

```
{"-Kh8M0qTdXJ-vBXr1G8v":{"email":"maad@yahoo.com","user":"amad"},"-Kh8M0v7KubmISGYrzks":{"email":"maad@yahoo.com","user":"amad"},"-KhB5OYsWias6j4Mc-pX":{"email":"faraz@yahoo.com","user":"faraz"},"-KhBBZ5Ii6kHPoUFhbj8":{"email":"zeeshan@gmail.com","user":"zeeshan"},"-KhBDTyGM9LaojajmtQv":{"email":"Ali@gmail.com","user":"Ali"}}
```

I want to print all email and user values. Can anyone help, how can I fetch these values from JSON using python?

Comment: You can use the built-in `json` library for this.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in json_dict.values():
    print(d['user'], ':', d['email'])
```

Where `json_dict` is the json file you've got