# Parse JSON file using Python and save the values into variables and arrays

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a `JSON` file with the following details:

```
{
"Name":"TESTING",
"Place":"India",
"Path":"Road",
"Details":
[
  {
    "city":"",
    "landmark":"aaabbbcccc",
    "pin":"500001"
  },
  {
    "city":"",
    "landmark":"aaabbbcccc",
    "pin":"500001"
  },
  {
    "city":"",
    "landmark":"xxxyyyzzzz",
    "pin":"510009"
  }
]
}
```

I want to parse the above json file and fetch the Name, Place, Path and store them into variables and then fetch city, landmark and pin and store them into arrays. How can i do this in Python. I've tried searching but all I could find is just reading the json file but not parsing it this way.

My Python code for reading the json:

```
import glob, os, json
from pprint import pprint
jsonfile = "testing.json"
with open('C:/Users/dev/Desktop/JSONSTest/'+jsonfile) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

Comment: You've done the parsing. Now `data` is a nested Python dictionary. There is nothing magical you need to do.

Comment: How do i store them into my own variable names; like sname = "TESTING"

Comment: Same way as any other dictionary lookup. If you don't know how to retrieve a key from a dictionary, you should do a [basic Python tutorial](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Comment: Variable assignment like this sname = data['Name']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Comment: @KishoreDevaraj thanks. it helped. one last query. how can i get the city, landmark and pin from the  file? using scity = data['city'] didn't fetch me any results.

Comment: City, landmark, pin are in Detail list. you should try scity = data['Details'][0]['city']. Also like Daniel Roseman suggested take a look at that course. Learn about python dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks Kishore and Daniel. i tried the possibilities and it worked. I'll go through the documentations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get cities:

```
for i in data['Details']:
    print i['city']
```