# How do i retrieve a value using TinyDB?

Tags: python, database, tinydb

I've recently started coded in python and just started using TinyDB.
I got the insert, remove and update working but i can't figure out how to retrieve a value from my data.

```
{"_default": {"1": {"name": "Sarah", "value": 8}, "2": {"name": "John", "value": 9}}}
```

How do i get the value from a specific name for example?

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [read from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('<your json path>')

# Get data from `Sarah`
result = db.get(Query()['name'] == 'Sarah')
```

Then your value should be `result.get('value')`