# GCP - is there any api exposed to create jsonl file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, jsonlines

Please help with GCP - automl api which can be used in c# code, such that we can pass gcp bucket location and output received is jsonl (same as jsonl received when we import document to dataset using google console)

Thanks

Comment: Could you share more details as code, the input you are sending and the output you get? As well the expected output

Comment: This could resolve your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475635/loading-jsonl-file-as-json-objects