# Json file parameter on Pycharm

Tags: python, json, twitter, pycharm

I'm running `twitter_hashtag_frequency.py` program on Pycharm with `json file` parameter and I have this error :

```
['C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Bonzanini_Book_Exercises/twitter_hashtag_frequency.py', 'stream_.jsonl']
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Bonzanini_Book_Exercises/twitter_hashtag_frequency.py", line 17, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

This is the code:

```
# Chap02-03/twitter_hashtag_frequency.py
import sys
from collections import Counter
import json

def get_hashtags(tweet):
    entities = tweet.get('entities', {})
    hashtags = entities.get('hashtags', [])
    return [tag['text'].lower() for tag in hashtags]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        hashtags = Counter()
        for line in f:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            hashtags_in_tweet = get_hashtags(tweet)
            hashtags.update(hashtags_in_tweet)
        for tag, count in hashtags.most_common(20):
            print("{}: {}".format(tag, count))
```

As you see in the screenshot the json file `stream_.jsonl`is in the same path with the program [Pycharm running window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q22Ir.png)

The windows of edit configuration sounds like good this is the screenshoot [Run debug configurations screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRp5L.png)

The `json file` file is an output of streaming tweets of 4629 lines. I would have your help, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading JSONL file as JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475635/loading-jsonl-file-as-json-objects)

Comment: My script is about to extract the hashtags from a json file and your answer refer to the loading file. I don't think that the situations are the same.

Comment: Try `json.loads(line.strip())`?

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: I change the code and put the path of the json file, I still have the same error.