# Merge multiple JSON files into one file by using Python (stream twitter)

Tags: python, json, api, twitter

I've pulled data from Twitter. Currently, the data is in multiple files and I could not merge it into one single file.

Note: all files are in JSON format.

The code I have used is [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python/blob/master/tools/search_tweets.py) and [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python).

[It has been suggested](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to work with `glop` [to compile JSON files](https://ispycode.com/Python/Files-and-directories/Modules/Directory-And-File-Examples/Unix-Style-Pathname-Pattern-Expansion)

I write this code as I have seen in some tutorials about merge JSON by using Python

```
from glob import glob 
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('Desktop/json/finalmerge.json', 'w') as f: 
    for fname in glob('Desktop/json/*.json'): # Reads all json from the current directory 
        with open(fname) as j: 
            f.write(str(j.read())) 
            f.write('\n')
```

I successfully merge all files and now the file is finalmerge.json.

Now I used this as suggested in several threads:

```
df_lines = pd.read_json('finalmerge.json', lines=True)
df_lines
1000000*23 columns
```

Then, what I should do to make each feature in separate columns?

I'm not sure why what's wrong with JSON files, I checked the file that I merge and I found it's not valid as JSON file? what I should do to make this as a data frame?

The reason I am asking this is that I have very basic python knowledge and all the answers to similar questions that I have found are way more complicated than I can understand. Please help this new python user to convert multiple JSON files to one JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your files are not really json (or better, they are structured as [jsonl](https://jsonlines.org/) ). You have two ways of proceding:

1. you could read every file as a text file and merge them line by line
2. you could convert them to json (add a square bracket at the beginning of the file and a comma at the end of every json element).

Try following this question and let me know if it solves your problem: [Loading JSONL file as JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475635/loading-jsonl-file-as-json-objects)

You can also try to edit your code this way:

```
with open('finalmerge.json', 'w') as f:
    for fname in glob('Desktop/json/*.json'): 
        with open(fname) as j:
            f.write(str(j.read()))
            f.write('\n')
```

Every line will be a different json element.

Comment: It's work but only with one file, so I don't know how to make it work for multiple files on the same time?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be something like this:

from glob import glob

with open('finalmerge.json', 'w') as f:
    for fname in glob('Desktop/json/*.json'):  # Reads all json from the current directory
        with open(fname) as j:
            f.write(str(j.read()))
            f.write('\n')
I will write this in my main answer

Comment: Thank you, the merge fils is generated but it's really large, now if I want to convert it to panda as the data frame is there a specific instruction to do it correctly since I don't know this jsonl .Second, how I validate the JSON file .due to its size is there is a way I double-check if the data frame in panda will not be rejected the file

Comment: In the pandas documentation you can find the lines option while reading a json file. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

The easiest way to check if the generated file is ok is just to scroll it quickly and see if there's some weird lines

Comment: I realized that the file that I merge is not valid JSON file . I  will write this in my main question.

Comment: Can’t you use this line of code to load your data in a data frame? df = pd.read_json(‘finalmerge.json’,lines=True)

Comment: Thank you for your comment , I don't think I do understand the code you have added? what is lines = True ?

Comment: lines = True is a parameter that will be passed to pandas read_json function, to let it know that the file is a jsonl file. I haven’t checked but I’m sure that the json_normalize has the same parameter available

Comment: Thank you , it put all the data in one line ? is that correct ? I add the result to the main question

Comment: Can you show me the file? Just to be sure on how the files are merged.I will try to help you as much as I can :)

Comment: df_lines = pd.read_json('finalmerge.json', lines=True)
df_lines


1000000*23 columns 

Then, what I should do to make each feature in separate columns? . I want to share the file but due to the size of the file  I don't be able to open it (out of memory)

Comment: Can you just share the first 30 lines of it? If you managed to create the Dataframe then you should be able to user every column as a feature

Comment: I created the data frame, but it was fill of NAN , then I checked several files and I found that the problem is JSON files need to be valid before I merge them, please correct me If I'm wrong? is setting lines=True is not the reasons to create NAN , my concern is my files are not JSON actually that makes me feel hopeless.Please when you said 30 lines do you the results or the file after the merge?

Comment: Yes, just so I can try it on my pc. Thanks