# Best approach to fix this JSON file

Tags: python, json, format

i have a huge JSON file that looks like this. I'm pasting an image because i think it's better to see the problem.

[image]

It's not inside brackets and there's no comma separating one entry from the other.

How can i make this a valid JSON file using python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly we have Open this URL:
https://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
And Paste your json Data and click on format menu  item.
After That you can view easily in tree strcutures(Viewer Tab).

Comment: This is [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org/) format. You can read it with pandas for instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909643/13525512