# Using BeautifulSoup4 to retrieve javascript dictionary value from html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the "album_release_date" value on a web page. It is listed in a script tag in what looks like a dictionary value on the page and I am not sure if it can be accessed with bs4. The only solution I can think of is using regex, would that be the best method?

Here is the structure of the page's source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var TralbumData = {

    current: {
        "upc":null,"title":"BLACK&WHITE MEDICINE","purchase_title":null,
        "download_desc_id":null,"minimum_price":0.0,"set_price":7.0,"mod_date":"17 Jun 2018 11:47:50 GMT"
    },
    album_is_preorder: null,
    album_release_date: "17 Jun 2018 00:00:00 GMT",
}
</script>
```

I have searched all over, but could not find anything outside of accessing the dictionaries that are exported from bs4.

Comment: Use the regex `current: {(.|\s)+?}` to get the `current` object as a string and then [parse it as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Comment: @GalAbra `album_release_date` isn't a subkey of `current`, it's a top-level key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BS4 parses HTML, so you can use it to find the contents of this `script` tag. For example, if this is the only script in you page:

```
script = soup.script.text
```

But it doesn't parse JavaScript.

So, you have a few choices:

- Download (or write) a JavaScript interpreter, use it to execute the code in the script, and then inspect it to see the variable and value it placed into the JS globals.
- Download (or write) a JavaScript parser, then scan the nodes for the `var` statement you're looking for and extract and interpret its value.
- Write a parser for a limited subset of JavaScript that will handle this specific case, but raise a noisy exception if they later rewrite their page to do something completely different in the `script` tag.

Which one you want to do depends on what you're trying to accomplish. But I suspect the last one is what you actually want here. In which case there isn't going to be anything off-the-shelf that does all the work for you. But you can cheat.

You don't actually need the whole `TralbumData` value, just the `album_release_date` member of it. So the grammar can be as simple as [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/eTFVlN/1):

```
r'album_release_date: \"(.*?)\"'
```

So:

```
script = soup.script.text
reldatematch = re.search(r'album_release_date: \"(.*?)\"', script)
if reldatematch:
    reldate = your_date_parser_func(reldatematch.group(1))
```

Whether you want to make this more robust is up to you.

If, say, you want to verify that this is actually the `TralbumData.album_release_date` value, not just something that happens to match `album_release_date`, then the grammar you want is just `var TralbumData = OBJECT_LITERAL`, and that `OBJECT_LITERAL` is almost JSON, except that it has bare keys. The first part, you could handle with just string methods:

```
empty, lead, literal = script.partition('var TralbumData = ')
if empty or not lead:
    raise SomeException
```

And for parsing the `literal`, you could adapt a JSON parser like the [JSON example for `pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/jsonParser.py) or [the stdlib's `json` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/json). Or, alternatively, you could do something hacky like pre-quoting all the keys and then just `json.loads` it.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thanks for listing the options, really helpful for  me. I will probably go with the regex option then.

Answer (score 0):

Extract script content and use regular expressions to extract the object

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


html = '''<script type="text/javascript">

        var TralbumData = {

            current: {
                "upc":null,"title":"BLACK&WHITE MEDICINE","purchase_title":null,
                "download_desc_id":null,"minimum_price":0.0,"set_price":7.0,"mod_date":"17 Jun 2018 11:47:50 GMT"
            },
            album_is_preorder: null,
            album_release_date: "17 Jun 2018 00:00:00 GMT",
        }
        </script>'''



pattern = re.compile(r'album_release_date: \"(.*?)\"', re.MULTILINE)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
script = soup.script.text
release_date = re.search(pattern, script).group(1)
print (release_date)
```