# how to convert abstruse string to list

Tags: python, json, string

I want to convert

```
'["$.insert(\"//localhost:0000/aaaa/js/\", function() {});", "$.functions($)(\"//localhost:0000/aaa2/js/\", function() {});", "$.placeholder.id+\"&_uid=\"+$.p.token+\"&_ref=\"+$.p.url;"]'
```

to

```
["$.insert(\"//localhost:0000/aaaa/js/\", function() {});", "$.functions($)(\"//localhost:0000/aaa2/js/\", function() {});", "$.placeholder.id+\"&_uid=\"+$.p.token+\"&_ref=\"+$.p.url;"]
```

In Django JSON:

```
{

"templates": ["$.insert(\"//localhost:0000/aaaa/js/\", function() {});", 
"$.functions($)(\"//localhost:0000/aaa2/js/\", function() {});", "$.placeholder.id+\"&_uid=\"+$.p.token+\"&_ref=\"+$.p.url;"]

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like JSON -> `json.loads()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)