# convert array of strings inside of string into a python list

Tags: python, json, django, parsing

I've sent some form-data from my React client to my Django + DRF api.

inside of the form-data I have an attribute `date_strings` which is an array of date-time strings. i.e. ["date1", "date2", "date3"]

in order to send it to my Django api I converted the array of strings into a string using JSON.stringify

```
const myForm = new FormData();
myForm.set("date_strings", JSON.stringify(dateStrings));
```

in the create method of my serializer, I'd like to convert this data into a list.

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
    stringified_array = validated_data.pop('date_strings')
    // stringified_array: '["date1", "date2", "date3"]'
```

how can I convert an array of strings inside of a string into a python list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Comment: I've tried using json.loads but it doesn't work. I think this is because this is an array and not formatted json

Comment: [Works just fine for me](https://repl.it/@ugam44/SlushySupportiveHexadecimal). Are you certain that your data is in the format posted above?

Comment: I'll double check to confirm

Comment: I think the problem is probably with your input, `[", "name": "server.posts.serializers", 
"levelname": "INFO", "request_id": "none"}` doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: @mhodges you were correct, this might be a duplicate although the data structure is different.

Comment: @BrooklinMyers Yeah, json array vs json object - parsing them is no different, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily turn strings into lists using `.split`. However, you have to remove the outermost characters `["` and  `"]` because otherwise these will also be added to your list of strings.

```
stringified = '["date1", "date2", "date3"]'
unstringified = stringified[2:-2].split('", "')
```

returns

```
['date1', 'date2', 'date3']
```

**A much better solution as mentioned by @mhodges**

```
import json
stringified = '["date1", "date2", "date3"]'
unstringified = json.loads(stringified)
```

Which also outputs:

```
['date1', 'date2', 'date3']
```

Comment: Isn't he doing the `json.loads()` solution?

Comment: This is the correct answer! I made a mistake, json.loads() works correctly.

I tried using json.loads before, but I had a log below it so kept getting the message `["TypeError: must be str, not type\n"]`