# How can I parse JSON API using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a REST Api that only renders this data

```
data:   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I need to store this XXXXXXXXXX value in some variable using python, but I could only code and reach to the part where I get this value `data:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`
my code is as follows

```
r = requests.get('url', headers=headers, verify=False)
logger.info(r)
```

which gives the output `data:   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`
How can i fetch only `XXXXXXXXXXXX` from this json output ?

Comment: do data = r.json(), then do data['data']

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python) could be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this could work for you.

```
r = requests.get('url', headers=headers, verify=False).json()
print(r['data'])
```