# How to replace multiple values in matching pattern from string

Tags: python, regex

I want to search a pattern in a string and then again search some invalid character in matching pattern and then remove them or replace with some valid characters.

I have some sample dictionaries eg. `sample_dict = {"randomId":"123y"   uhnb\n g", "desc": ["sample description"]}`

In this case I want to find the value of a dictionary let say "123y"    uhnb\n g" and then remove invalid characters in it such as (", \t, \n) etc..
what I have tried is stored all the dictionaries in a file then read file and matching pattern for dictionary value, but this gives me a list of matching pattern, I can also compile these matches but I am not sure how to perform replace in original dictionary value so my final output will be:
`{"randomId":"123y uhnb g", "desc": ["sample description"]}`

```
pattern = re.findall("\":\"(.+?)\"", sample_dict)
```

expected result:

```
{"randomId":"123y uhnb g", "desc": ["sample description"]}
```

actual result:

```
['123y" uhnb\n g']
```

Comment: Don't parse JSON with regex, use a JSON parser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Comment: @miken32: I can use json parser but in that case as well I need to remove those invalid characters else it won't work, so in order to remove those characters I am using regex.

Comment: How did you end up with this strange `sample_dict` to begin with? Perhaps you can avoid that already earlier so that you do not need to replace or remove the strange characters.

Comment: Why are you using re.findall instead of re.sub (in some capacity)?

Comment: Secondly, why are you passing a dictionary to findall as opposed to a string? Are you implying that you convert the regex to a string, or are you inserting the randomid key's value?

Comment: As suggested, using re.sub is easier to replace non-alphanumeric characters, check my answer below to see how! @Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

You can just substitute non-alphanumeric characters in your value using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)
as below

```
dct = {"randomId":"123y uhnb\n g", "desc": ["sample description"]}
import re

for key, value in dct.items():
    val = None
    #If the value is a string, directly substitute
    if isinstance(value, str):
       val = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", '', str(value))
    #If value is a list, substitute for all string in the list
    elif isinstance(value, list):
       val = []
       for item in value:
           val.append(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ' ', str(item)))
    dct[key] = val

print(dct)
#{'randomId': '123y uhnb g', 'desc': ['sample description']}
```