# How to access to .json data?

Tags: python, json, csv

Can anybody help me to get data from the json below.I have the  json data in the format below

```
[
  {
    "methods": [
      {
        "parametersTypes": [
          "int",
          "Menu"
        ],
        "sourceFile": {
          "file": {
            "path": "/mnt/c/anyplace-master/android/actionbarsherlock/src/android/support/v4/app/Watson.java"
      }
    },
    "metricsValues": {
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 33.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 13.0,
      "CouplingDispersion": 0.6666666666666666,
      "MaxNesting": 5.0,
      "ChangingClasses": 0.0,
      "ParameterCount": 2.0,
      "CouplingIntensity": 3.0,
      "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 13.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 1.0,
      "ChangingMethods": 0.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu",
    "smells": [
      {
        "name": "LongMethod",
        "reason": "MLOC > 6.74646840148693",
        "startingLine": 39,
        "endingLine": 82
      }
    ]
```

I need just  the value of the key "name" which is "longMethod"

```
"name": "LongMethod"
```

NB: this block is a part of my JSON file and it repeats

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What problems did you have using the `json` module from the standard library?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: can you please fix this module /part of json which is repeating, in given example it's incomplete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your file with `json` :

```
import json
with open('your_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

and access your variable with :

```
data[0]['methods']['smells'][0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my educated guess about the incomplete json is correct this is what you do

```
s="""[
    {
        "methods": 
        [
            {
                "parametersTypes":
                [
                    "int",
                    "Menu"
                ],
                "sourceFile": 
                {
                    "file": 
                    {
                        "path": "/mnt/c/anyplace-master/android/actionbarsherlock/src/android/support/v4/app/Watson.java"
                    }
                },
                "metricsValues": 
                {
                  "MethodLinesOfCode": 33.0,
                  "CyclomaticComplexity": 13.0,
                  "CouplingDispersion": 0.6666666666666666,
                  "MaxNesting": 5.0,
                  "ChangingClasses": 0.0,
                  "ParameterCount": 2.0,
                  "CouplingIntensity": 3.0,
                  "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 13.0,
                  "MaxCallChain": 1.0,
                  "ChangingMethods": 0.0
                },
                "fullyQualifiedName": "android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu",
                "smells": 
                [
                    {
                        "name": "LongMethod",
                        "reason": "MLOC > 6.74646840148693",
                        "startingLine": 39,
                        "endingLine": 82
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]"""

import json
d=json.loads(s)
print(d[0]["methods"][0]["smells"][0]["name"])
```

Comment: thank but it return a list like this LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod
LongMethod i need the name of smells on each block

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
data = [
  {
    "methods": [
      {
        "parametersTypes": [
          "int",
          "Menu"
        ],
        "sourceFile": {
          "file": {
            "path": "/mnt/c/anyplace-master/android/actionbarsherlock/src/android/support/v4/app/Watson.java"
      }
    },
    "metricsValues": {
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 33.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 13.0,
      "CouplingDispersion": 0.6666666666666666,
      "MaxNesting": 5.0,
      "ChangingClasses": 0.0,
      "ParameterCount": 2.0,
      "CouplingIntensity": 3.0,
      "NumberOfAccessedVariables": 13.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 1.0,
      "ChangingMethods": 0.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu",
    "smells": [
      {
        "name": "LongMethod",
        "reason": "MLOC > 6.74646840148693",
        "startingLine": 39,
        "endingLine": 82
      }
    ]
          }
          ]
  }
]

print(data[0]['methods'][0]['smells'][0]['name'])
```

You might need to make it dynamic by using indexing methods. You can use `type` method of python to check the subsquent type of your data such as `type(data), type(data[0]), type(data[0]['methods'])`, it will help you understand it better.