# Parsing Json in Python and find a value

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse following Json using Python and the json library

```
{"attributes":{"173":{"id":"173","code":"Size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"352","label":"Footwear-41","products":["78834"]},{"id":"355","label":"Footwear-42","products":["78835"]},{"id":"357","label":"Footwear-42.5","products":["78836"]},{"id":"358","label":"Footwear-43","products":["78837"]},{"id":"361","label":"Footwear-44","products":["78838"]},{"id":"363","label":"Footwear-44.5","products":["78839"]},{"id":"364","label":"Footwear-45","products":["78840"]},{"id":"367","label":"Footwear-46","products":["78841"]}],"position":"0"}},"template":"<%- data.price %>\u00a0 \u20ac","currencyFormat":"%s\u00a0 \u20ac","optionPrices":{"78834":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78835":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78836":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78837":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78838":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78839":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78840":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]},"78841":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9},"tierPrices":[]}},"priceFormat":{"pattern":"%s\u00a0 \u20ac","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":",","groupSymbol":".","groupLength":3,"integerRequired":1},"prices":{"oldPrice":{"amount":189.9},"basePrice":{"amount":159.57983093277},"finalPrice":{"amount":189.9}},"productId":"78842","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","images":[],"index":{"78834":{"173":"352"},"78835":{"173":"355"},"78836":{"173":"357"},"78837":{"173":"358"},"78838":{"173":"361"},"78839":{"173":"363"},"78840":{"173":"364"},"78841":{"173":"367"}},"sku":{"default":"CI6400-100","78834":"CI6400-100-Footwear-41","78835":"CI6400-100-Footwear-42","78836":"CI6400-100-Footwear-42.5","78837":"CI6400-100-Footwear-43","78838":"CI6400-100-Footwear-44","78839":"CI6400-100-Footwear-44.5","78840":"CI6400-100-Footwear-45","78841":"CI6400-100-Footwear-46"},"stock":{"78834":{"is_salable":true,"qty":1},"78835":{"is_salable":true,"qty":2},"78836":{"is_salable":true,"qty":3},"78837":{"is_salable":true,"qty":3},"78838":{"is_salable":true,"qty":3},"78839":{"is_salable":true,"qty":1},"78840":{"is_salable":true,"qty":3},"78841":{"is_salable":true,"qty":1}}}
```

I want to get the 'products' value for a specific footwear size, ex. if I want it for 42, find 78835.

I tried to do it in two ways:

1.

```
tex=THEJSONTEXT
jsn=json.loads(tex)
jsn['attributes']['173'].get("products","")
```

But this doesn't work for me.
So I tried version 2:

```
import re
prod=re.findall('"Footwear-42","products":["\d\d\d\d\d"]', tex)
```

And even this didnt work for me....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> jsn['attributes']['173'].keys()
dict_keys(['id', 'code', 'label', 'options', 'position'])
```

As you can see product isn't there, which is why the code isn't working. You're correctly parsing the JSON.

Formatting the JSON just a bit

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "173": {
      "id": "173",
      "code": "Size",
      "label": "Size",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "352",
          "label": "Footwear-41",
          "products": [
            "78834"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "355",
          "label": "Footwear-42",
          "products": [
            "78835"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "357",
          "label": "Footwear-42.5",
          "products": [
            "78836"
          ]
        },

... much more
```

And it gets a little easier to drill down into the JSON. The only attribute I see relating to size is in the `label` key for the various options. Is that correct? If so, you'll have to filter on the keys then for the `options` list to do what you want.

so.. imagine the options list is assigned like this:

```py
options = obj['attributes']['173']['options']
```

Then you can filter the list down to the products you want like this:

```py
>>> size = 42
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x['label'][-1 * len(str(size)):] == str(size), options))
[{'id': '355', 'label': 'Footwear-42', 'products': ['78835']}]
```

---

so, what does `lambda x: x['label'][-1 * len(str(size)):]` do? It's a lambda which effectively does this:

```py
size = 42
def filter_product(product_object):
    label = product_object['label']
    product_size = [-1 * len(str(size)):]  # get the last digits of the str that are the size
    if str(size) == product_size:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I look at the last `n` digits of the label based on how long the size float/int is. And then I compare that to the size you want, and if it is the same, then this is the product you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is one more level of nesting. Try the below.

```
for i in jsn['attributes']['173']["options"]:
    print(i["products"])
```

Also the `options` is a list.