# How split json file in dataframe python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a .txt file, named 'data.txt' which is a list of dictionaries, i.e., something like,

```
{"958464": ["item1", "item3"], "917654": [], "1347584": ["item2", "item5", "item6", "item7"], "914082": [], "946178": ["item1", "item4", "item15"], ...}
```

How can form a dataframe, with the above file?

My idea is cross information (about ID) with another database, so I think form dataframe like,

```
      ID            ITEMS
0    958464    "item1", "item3"
1    917654
2    1347584   "item2", "item5", "item6", "item7"
3    914082
4    946178    "item1", "item3", "item5"
...
```

Or maybe, create a dataframe like

```
      ID        Item1   item2   item3   ...
0    958464       1      0        1
1    917654       0      0        0
2    1347584      0      1        0   
3    914082       0      0        0
4    946178       1      0        1
...
```

I tried

```
data = pd.read_csv('data1.txt')
pd.DataFrame(data.items())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
k = {"958464": ["item1", "item3"], "917654": [],
 "1347584": ["item2", "item5", "item6", "item7"], "914082": [], "946178": ["item1", "item4", "item15"]}

import pandas

df1=pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(k,orient='index')
print(df1)
```

O/P :

```
             0      1       2      3
958464   item1  item3    None   None
917654    None   None    None   None
1347584  item2  item5   item6  item7
914082    None   None    None   None
946178   item1  item4  item15   None
```