# What libraries and concepts should I learn to parse data from a webpage?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to parse data from a website that has all universities listed in something like this

```
{
    "web_pages": [
      "http://www.marywood.edu"
    ],
    "name": "Marywood University",
    "alpha_two_code": "PA",
    "state-province": null,
    "domains": [
      "marywood.edu"
    ],
    "country": "United States"
  }
```

How can I add each university name to a list and its country code too?

Comment: If it helps, that's JSON data which you could parse with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) from the stdlib

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771011/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn the basics of `webbrowser`, `requests` and `bs4`. You can also read Chapter 11 of "Automate The Boring Stuff with Python" by Al Swigart, which gives detailed explanations of everything needed.