# Extracting numbers from LIST of STRING and assigning them to another list depending on their label

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of STRINGS each containing line of text like following:

```
{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[319,469,573,685,786,1005,1008,839,684,576,515,335,319],"all_points_y":[374,310,275,249,232,211,213,230,255,280,300,374,374]}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []

iterate through list:
    extract numbers
    append to x_coordinates if they belong to "all_points_x":
    otherwise append to y_coordinates if they belong to "all_points_y"
```

But I am not sure how to do this at all.

Comment: your example input appears to be a dict, not a list. your dict contains string keys and some of the values are lists of int.

Comment: Is this json? See [How to parse data in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771011/4518341)

Comment: It is string extracted from CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have there is actually a dictionary rather than a list of strings. Dictionaries are a nice tool in python because they allow you to work with a key to access data. For example in your dictionary the keys are "name", "all_points_x", and "all_points_y" which when called return the respective values of ["polygon"] (this is a str), [319,469,573,685,786,1005,1008,839,684,576,515,335,319] (these are all ints), and [374,310,275,249,232,211,213,230,255,280,300,374,374] (also ints). So a simple answer to your question would be...

```
d = {"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[319,469,573,685,786,1005,1008,839,684,576,515,335,319],"all_points_y":[374,310,275,249,232,211,213,230,255,280,300,374,374]}

x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []

for i in d["all_points_x"]:
    x_coordinates.append(i)

for i in d["all_points_y"]:
    y_coordinates.append(i)

print(x_coordinates)
print(y_coordinates)
```

EDIT: Try something like this, converting the pandas element into a dictionary. (not sure what this will do to your keys)

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
d = data.to_dict()
...
```

EDIT2: I think this should be all you need, assuming you want ALL the x's and y's together.

```
import pandas
import json

x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []

data = pandas.read_csv("C://Users//Zak//Documents//Testing//dataset.csv")
data2 = list(data["region_shape_attributes"].values)

for i in data2:
    d = json.loads(i)
    for x in d["all_points_x"]:
        x_coordinates.append(x)
    for y in d["all_points_y"]:
        y_coordinates.append(y)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am having a problem that I have read this from CSV file like: data = pandas.read_csv("data.csv") and then d = list(data["region_shape_attributes"].values), so I would get: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str running the code you've just written.

Comment: Sorry I see now that you mentioned it was coming from a csv file. Any chance I could peak at it or a trimmed down version of the csv file?

Comment: Yeah, it was in comment so my question was probably not the best.

Comment: I've uploaded the file here: https://anonfile.com/U2Cao610n8/dataset_csv Thanks for the help! :)