# python parse multiple keys

Tags: json, dictionary, parsing

I have an API returning a response like this one.

```
data = [
  {'id': 'x27fujsjfsfjsjf', 'price': '89992',  'type': 'ONE'}, {'id': 'ujufajfjfwau', 'price': '7777',  'type': 'ONE'}, {'id': 'x27adarasda', 'price': '88882',  'type': 'TWO'}
]
```

I would like to parse the response in pairs for example id and price. I use the python Websocket client to fetch data in real time.

Right now I use:

```
 for d in data: 
       print (d['id])
```

But I can't find a solution to parse both the id,price and type together. Since I'm interested of price for a particular ID.

Comment: Did you miss a comma inside each object or is it like that?

Comment: No, Fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, you just want to print the id, price and type together?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I don't know how it can be so hard to figure out for me :(  Seems like an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
for d in data:
    print (d['id'], d['price'], d['type'])
```

You can pass the values in the same way to another function, if you want to use these values somewhere.

A lot more information is available in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to 'say' what you want to print from the dictionary:

```
data = [
        {'id': 'x27fujsjfsfjsjf', 'price': '89992', 'type': 'ONE'},
        {'id': 'ujufajfjfwau', 'price': '7777',  'type': 'ONE'},
        {'id': 'x27adarasda', 'price': '88882',  'type': 'TWO'}
]

for item in data:
    print(item['id']) # this prints out the value of the ID
    print(item['price']) # this prints out the value of the PRICE
    print(item['type']) # this prints out the value of the TYPE
```