# How to extract JSON using python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to extract a json. I'm having wrong extracted data for "error". When I try to do with `t3 = temp['errors'][0]` I'm getting only `"Arg one must not be null or empty."`

Expected output:

```
"Arg one must not be null or empty.",
"Arg two must not be null or empty."
```

Here is my json:

```
{
        "status": "Fail",
        "warnings": {
            "Code": "VALID",
            "Desc": "Invalid data",
            "errors": [
                "Arg one must not be null or empty.",
                "Arg two must not be null or empty."

            ]
        }
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
tmp = json.loads(res.content)
print(tmp['status'])
temp = (tmp['warnings'])
t1 = temp['errorCode']
t2 = temp['errorDesc']
t3 = temp['errors'][0]
print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Someone Please correct me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want both, why are you indexing with `[0]` at the end? That gets only the first from `errors`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate if I keep t3 = temp['errors'] then i'm getting [ "Arg one must not be null or empty.", "Arg two must not be null or empty." ] and I don't want [ ] brackets.

Comment: That's not "nested JSON". Its' just JSON.

Comment: Then use `', '.join` or something on the resulting list. The brackets are just part of the representation of the list. They aren't data. You only need to worry about them when printing data out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse data in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json)

Comment: You can just loop through the indexing of errors.

Comment: @nancy Be careful, I **strongly recommend** making sure that you understand things clearly. The brackets are not just some random visual thing, they indicate a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try just:

```
t3 = temp['errors']
```

```
t3
# ['Arg one must not be null or empty.', 
# 'Arg two must not be null or empty.']
```

you get the brackets because it's a list, if you want to concatenate the two into a string you can do this:

```
', '.join( temp['errors'] )
# 'Arg one must not be null or empty., Arg two must not be null or empty.'
```

that will create a string of the contents, without the brackets