# retrieve json value python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON value and would like to retrieve each value in it.

```
{"profile": [{"user_id": "91609430", "user_phone": "6525295", "user_type": "panger", "user_tier": "silver", "user_name": "Robert Sambuena", "user_email": "sauena.@gmail.com"}], "is_from_hc": false, "errors": [{"msg": "Driver Profile Not Found", "code": 404, "key": "profile.driver"}], "soundwaves": {"audio_messages": ["hc-education"], "access_token": "9f7fd8f060f2dc2fa", "has_context": false, "queue": "", "iso_language": "", "context": {"user_id": "", "user_tier": "", "user_name": "", "user_phone": "", "is_from_hc": false, "user_type": "", "has_context": false, "zendesk_language": "", "taxtype": "", "scenario_name": "", "zen_country": "", "booking_code": ""}}}
```

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-json-in-python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python built-in `json` lib for this task:

```
import json

json_str = '{"profile": [{"user_id": "91609430", "user_phone": "6525295", "user_type": "panger", "user_tier": "silver", "user_name": "Robert Sambuena", "user_email": "sauena.@gmail.com"}], "is_from_hc": false, "errors": [{"msg": "Driver Profile Not Found", "code": 404, "key": "profile.driver"}], "soundwaves": {"audio_messages": ["hc-education"], "access_token": "9f7fd8f060f2dc2fa", "has_context": false, "queue": "", "iso_language": "", "context": {"user_id": "", "user_tier": "", "user_name": "", "user_phone": "", "is_from_hc": false, "user_type": "", "has_context": false, "zendesk_language": "", "taxtype": "", "scenario_name": "", "zen_country": "", "booking_code": ""}}}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)

# Now you can iterate over the json_obj as you would do with any dict:
for k, v in json_obj.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: hi. thank you so much for the help. I only need this value [{u'user_id': u'91609430', u'user_phone': u'658402', u'user_type': u'passenger', u'user_tier': u'silver', u'user_name': u'Robert', u'user_email': u'sambu@gmail.com'}] how i can retrieve each of them?

Comment: have your tried to copy and paste my sample and play with it, @art?

Answer (score 0):

Using `yaml` lib in python: (Answer updated as per ur need)

```
import yaml

json_str = '{"profile": [{"user_id": "91609430", "user_phone": "6525295", "user_type": "panger", "user_tier": "silver", "user_name": "Robert Sambuena", "user_email": "sauena.@gmail.com"}], "is_from_hc": false, "errors": [{"msg": "Driver Profile Not Found", "code": 404, "key": "profile.driver"}], "soundwaves": {"audio_messages": ["hc-education"], "access_token": "9f7fd8f060f2dc2fa", "has_context": false, "queue": "", "iso_language": "", "context": {"user_id": "", "user_tier": "", "user_name": "", "user_phone": "", "is_from_hc": false, "user_type": "", "has_context": false, "zendesk_language": "", "taxtype": "", "scenario_name": "", "zen_country": "", "booking_code": ""}}}'
json_obj = yaml.load(json_str)
# Retrive the Profile Value like this
profile = json_obj['profile']
print(profile)
# Iterate to get each value in profile
for i in profile:
    for j in i:
        print(j," : ", i[j])
```