# How to parse a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I know there are a lot of questions like these but I am not able to find an answer to my question. Or probably, I am missing something here. The format of my JSON is:

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "long",
            "name": "UniqId",
            "data": "True"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "Name",
            "data": "True"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "Address",
            "data": "False"
        }
    ],
    "type": "struct"
}
```

I just want **name** and **type** to be extracted and appended to a list. First element to be name and second to be type. 
The above format is saved in a variable json_dump. And when I do:

```
for k in json_dump1.iteritems():
    print k
```

It gives me an error

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems".

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a json parsing library.

Comment: a) are you using Python 2? It's no longer supported, so upgrade if you can. b) you need to deserialise the string with `json.loads()`

Comment: Your `json_dump1` is a string, it doesn't have `iteritems` as an attribute. You need to parse the string using a json library: ```import json
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)```

Comment: @SamiFarhat please turn your comment into an answer, comments do not allow proper formatting.

Comment: What do/don’t you understand from that error message? Also, **please share a [mcve]**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

`json_dump1` is a string, so you need to parse it into an object first. This can be done with the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json
parsed_json = json.loads(json_dump1)
```

It sounds like you also want to do some comprehension on this. It's unclear exactly how you want the `name` and `type` values to be stored, but you would want something like this to iterate over `parsed_json`:

```
results = []
for f in parsed_json['fields']:
    results.append(f['name'])
    results.append(f['type'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the code but I get the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @Jupyter can you show me what code you tried to run?

Comment: It worked well. I was missing out the list while defining. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this, it's better to think of the json as a dictionary containing nested lists or dictionaries within them. So if you treat them as such and iterate over the lists/keys you should be fine. In this case, the first key is `fields`, after that we have a number of lists that each contain a dictionary, so we iterate over each of these lists and extract the desired keys (`name` and `type`):

```
name_list = []
type_list = []
for i in json_file['fields']:
    name_list.append(i['name'])
    type_list.append(i['type'])
print name_list
print type_list
```

Output:

```
['UniqId', 'Name', 'Address']
['long', 'string', 'string']
```

You can also create a dictionary in which you will append these values:

```
json_values = {'name':type_name,'list':type_list}
```

Of course you can define this first and append the values to the lists in the dictionaries:

```
json_values = {'name':[],'list':[]
name_list = []
type_list = []
for i in json_file['fields']:
    json_values['name'].append(i['name'])
    json_values['list'].append(i['type'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I tried, it gave me the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I copy pasted what you provided. Did you edit or changed something?