# Python Json serialization/deserialization

Tags: python, json, serialization

So I have this text file that has information on 1 person per line

input.txt

```
346-78-4956,Niels,Pirrone,npirrone2p@twitter.com:ID251,51:LD118,41:IT466,47
20141232,Patel,Dhruv:cs210,39:ece124,83
```

I was able to read it and serialize it into Json file as below

out.json

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "346-78-4956",
        "lastName": "Niels",
        "firstname": "Pirrone",
        "email": "npirrone2p@twitter.com",
        "ID251": "51",
        "LD118": "41",
        "IT466": "47"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "20141232",
        "lastName": "Patel",
        "firstname": "Dhruv",
        "cs210": "39",
        "ece124": "83 "
    }
}
```

Now, how can I read this json file and de-serialize it into same form I started with ?

I am trying to calculate how long it takes to serialize and de-serialize data using Json.

Comment: What did you use to serialize it?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it a substitute for guides, tutorials and documentation. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: As it stands, this is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-json-in-python.