# How to access data in JSON file in python? I want to access email data

Tags: python, json

I have created JSON file like this and I want to access email
this is the JSON file

```
{
            "customers": {
                "OscarLang": {
                    "email": "gmail@gmail.com",
                    "events": []
                },
                "foretz-abdo": {
                    "email": "hotmail@hotmail.com",
                    "events": []
                },
                "testuser": {
                    "email": "test@hotmail.com",
                    "events": []
                },
                "AAS": {
                    "email": "osdaadawdaw@asdad.com",
                    "events": []
                }
            }
        }
```

and this what I tried

```
 sources = ["customers.json"]
    for source in sources:
        data = util.get_data_item(source)
        if data is None or len(data) == 0:
            continue
        register = json.loads(data)
        for json_obj in register['customers']:
            print(json_obj)
            try:
                emailaddress = json_obj['email']
            except Exception as e:
                emailaddress = None

            print(emailaddress)
```

when I print emailaddress I get NONE

Comment: Hi Abdo, please read up on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next question! Happy coding :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-json-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow.

See if something like this will work for you:

**Project Tree:**

```
project
  |__customers.json
  |
  |__customers.py
```

**customers.json file**

```
{
  "customers": {
    "OscarLang": {
      "email": "gmail@gmail.com",
      "events": []
    },
    "foretz-abdo": {
      "email": "hotmail@hotmail.com",
      "events": []
    },
    "testuser": {
      "email": "test@hotmail.com",
      "events": []
    },
    "AAS": {
      "email": "osdaadawdaw@asdad.com",
      "events": []
    }
  }
}
```

**customers.py file**

```
# Import Python's json package
import json

# Specify the json file to work with
sources = 'customers.json'

# Open the json file
with open(sources) as json_file:
    # Extract the data from the json file
    data = json.load(json_file)

    # Iterate over each customer in the file
    for customer in data['customers']:
        # Print each customer's e-mail address
        try:
            email = data['customers'][customer]['email']
            print(email)
        except KeyError as err:
            print(f"Email not found for {customer}")
```

Comment: I tried this but I got this error  TypeError: list indices must be integers

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace for the error? I updated my answer to show the json file and format I used to run