# Python Extract variables from txt file

Tags: python, text

I have losts of Txt files all look similar to this:

```
{
  "securitiesEndOfDayTrading": {
    "result": [
      {
        "ISIN": "CA0295456365",
        "basePrice": 118.2,
        "capitalListedforTrading": 760000,
        "change": 1.33,
        "changeNis": 1.23,
        "closingPrice": 423,
        "high": 129.9,
        "lastTrade": "2020-05-04T15:31:18.726Z",
        "low": 117.5,
        "marketCap": 1159100,
        "minimumAmountForContinuousTradingPhase": 21000,
        "openingPrice": 118,
        "securityID": 10112,
        "symbol": "CA1420",
        "transactionsNumber": 21,
        "turnover": 424332,
        "volume": 494332
      }
    ],
    "total": 40
  }
}
```

I need to create a function which knows how to read this file and store values into variables, Example: create var named basePrice and assign value 118.2
Im new to python so not sure how it can be done, i wrote this:

```
data1 = "basePrice"

with open("Example.txt", "r") as f:  # Read file.
    for line in f:  # Loop through every line.
        line_split = line.split()  # Split line by whitespace.
        if data1 in line_split:
            #What now???
```

Comment: use `json` module to extract the dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-json-in-python)

Comment: Yes :) i was unaware of that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have python or json like data stored in file use `json` module to extract it

```
import json

with open("text_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

base_price = data['securitiesEndOfDayTrading']['result'][0]['basePrice']
```