# Loading JSON in Python and referencing via internal variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have JSON

```
[{"id": 1, "title": "ble", "description": "ble", "done": true}, {"id":2, "title": "2", "description": "2", "done": true}]
```

and I want to load it into a Python 3 dictionary, so then I can reference it via this `id` from JSON like `print(json[2])` would print it one item.

Comment: Are you just asking [how to parse JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771011/3001761)?

Comment: well just how to do this correctly in python because what I did seems incorrect

Comment: What _did_ you do? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `json` package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
import json

# some JSON:
stringifiedJSON = '[{"id": 1, "title": "ble", "description": "ble", "done": true}, {"id":2, "title": "2", "description": "2", "done": true}]'

# parse x:
parsedJSON = json.loads(stringifiedJSON) # a dict representing the JSON

# access specific field
print(parsedJson[1])
```

Output:
`>>> { "id":2, "title":"2", "description":"2", "done":true }`

Note that it would be impossible to access the key `2` in the JSON string sample you provided, since it is an array with only 2 elements (indices are zero-based).

Comment: It's still impossible to access the key `2`, see updated note.