# how to access the nested json data?

Tags: python, json

How do I access the `world_population` key data in the following json data using python ?

```json
{
  "ok": true,
  "body": { "world_population": 7795232630, "total_countries": 235 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse (read) and use JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-can-i-parse-read-and-use-json-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your json in a string format you can do it like this:

```
import json

your_json = '{"ok": true,"body": { "world_population": 7795232630,"total_countries": 235 }}'

parsed = json.loads(your_json)
print(parsed["body"]["world_population"])
```