# python string to list (in string and json)

Tags: python, json, string, list, types

I want to convert these strings to a list. in python

from
`42["pause",{"all":false,"media_only":false,"media_exclude":false}]`
(type : string)

to`["pause",{"all":false,"media_only":false,"media_exclude":false}]`
(type : list (in string and json))

There is a way to parse the string directly, but since the types of incoming data are various, I was looking for a function that can be converted directly, but I couldn't find it. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do it using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) is leading `42` is just a typo.

Comment: What does *"(type : list (in string and json))"* mean…?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format.

Comment: Since that data is data received through websocket, it is a number indicating the type of data.

Comment: @sub123, so `42` means `string`? Great number choice though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import json
text = '''42["pause",{"all":false,"media_only":false,"media_exclude":false}]'''
text = text[text.find('['):]
result = json.loads(text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['pause', {'all': False, 'media_only': False, 'media_exclude': False}]
```