# http dart: How to send a Map in the query parameters of a request?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, httprequest

I have a http request like this using the `http` package:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Uri url = Uri.http(
  'http://sample.com',
  '/request',
  {
    'dataMap': {
      'key1': ['item1', 'item2']
      'key2': ['item1', 'item2']
    },
  },
);
```

I get this error:

```
 _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')
```

The error is not thrown if I don't put a map in the query parameters.

So how do I send a `Map`?

Comment: can you please provide some more info. About methods and is the items in key list are fix or what. It would be good if you provide info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `jsonEncode` the map:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Uri url = Uri.http(
    'sample.com',
    '/request',
    {
      'dataMap': jsonEncode({
        'key1': ['item1', 'item2'],
        'key2': ['item1', 'item2']
      }),
    },
  );
  
  print(url);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. For anyone who might have the same problems as me, use `json.loads` to "decode" the map in python if you're using a flask backend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this way :

```
  _request() async {
    
    
    var outer = {};
    
    outer['dataMap'] =  {
          'key1': ['item1', 'item2'],
           'key2': ['item1', 'item2']
    };
    
    print(jsonEncode(outer));
 
    
    
    return  http.post(Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/request'), body: jsonEncode(outer));
    
    
  }
```