# How to convert JSON string to array in python

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am sending the array of dicts from javascript to python via a POST request that looks this way:

```
mydata.push({
            department_id: department_id,
            cardgroup_id: cardgroup,
            doorgroup_id: doorgroup
        });


$.post("data/save-office/"+office, {'data': JSON.stringify(mydata)}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        });
```

When extracting the payload in `python`:

```py
    departments = request.form.getlist('data')
```

The output is:

```
departments = ['[{"department_id":"1","cardgroup_id":"2","doorgroup_id":"2550"},
{"department_id":"2","cardgroup_id":"2","doorgroup_id":"2550"},
{"department_id":"3","cardgroup_id":"2","doorgroup_id":"2550"},
{"department_id":"4","cardgroup_id":"2","doorgroup_id":"2550"}]']
```

This displayed output is an array of one index and the inside is treated as a string rather than a dictionary.

How can I filter it or send it from javascript so that it can be decoded as an array of dicts not an array of strings?

Comment: There are a number of libraries for parsing JSON; you can probably guess what some of their names are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse data in JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your code, the simplest solution is using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library's `load` or `loads` (load safe) method

```
import json
departments_string = request.form.getlist('data')[0]
departments = json.loads(departments_string)
print(departments)
```

> [{'department_id': '1', 'cardgroup_id': '2', 'doorgroup_id': '2550'},
> {'department_id': '2', 'cardgroup_id': '2', 'doorgroup_id': '2550'},
> {'department_id': '3', 'cardgroup_id': '2', 'doorgroup_id': '2550'},
> {'department_id': '4', 'cardgroup_id': '2', 'doorgroup_id': '2550'}]

I would further question using `getlist`, but we would need more deatils from you to deal with that.