# Why I am getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?

Tags: python, json, typeerror

I have a input which looks like it is in json format
`{'server': 'apple'}`

while writing

[image]

It is throwing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`  error. What is wrong in this?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: What were you expecting to happen exactly? If `server = {'server': 'apple'}`, then `server['hostname']` would raise a KeyError. Is the value of `server` different? Please make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, the example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse data in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format)

Answer (score 0):

```py
servernames.append(server["hostname"])
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

The error message suggests `server` is a string, and it's complaining `"hostname"` is not an integer.

If `server` is a string containing JSON data, you can convert it with the `json` module:

```py
import json

server_names = []
for server in servers:
    server = json.loads(server)
    server_names.append(server["hostname"])
```

`json.loads` turns JSON data in a string into a Python object (`dict`, `list`, `str`, `float`, `int`, `bool`, or `None`).

You should investigate what `server` actually is, perhaps by printing it or using the debugger.

Comment: and if `server == '{"server":  "apple"}'`, you'd then get `KeyError` for trying to get `"hostname"` out of it, but that's Progress