# How to get Json content in another Json content by Regex

Tags: python, json, regex, jenkins, groovy

I have the Json content like this

```
{"expand": "names,schema","startAt": 0,"maxResults": 50,"total": 1,"issues": [{"expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields","id": "641955","self": "https://rb-tracker.bosch.com/tracker19/rest/api/latest/issue/641955","key": "EDATOOL-1411","fields": {"created": "2022-12-06T11:14:36.000+0100","customfield_10000": "{summaryBean=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryBean@24a1688f[summary={pullrequest=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryItemBean@23f2f23c[overall=PullRequestOverallBean{stateCount=0, state='OPEN', details=PullRequestOverallDetails{openCount=0, mergedCount=0, declinedCount=0}},byInstanceType={}], build=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryItemBean@321de5ab[overall=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.summary.beans.BuildOverallBean@6ca82c6[failedBuildCount=0,successfulBuildCount=0,unknownBuildCount=0,count=0,lastUpdated=<null>,lastUpdatedTimestamp=<null>],byInstanceType={}], review=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryItemBean@5fc3e1e6[overall=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.summary.beans.ReviewsOverallBean@7a2d42e3[stateCount=0,state=<null>,dueDate=<null>,overDue=false,count=0,lastUpdated=<null>,lastUpdatedTimestamp=<null>],byInstanceType={}], deployment-environment=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryItemBean@2740d0b0[overall=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.summary.beans.DeploymentOverallBean@75ceaa2c[topEnvironments=[],showProjects=false,successfulCount=0,count=0,lastUpdated=<null>,lastUpdatedTimestamp=<null>],byInstanceType={}], repository=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryItemBean@35c2a9a2[overall=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.summary.beans.CommitOverallBean@2568cfa3[count=0,lastUpdated=<null>,lastUpdatedTimestamp=<null>],byInstanceType={}], branch=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.rest.SummaryItemBean@40c4eee[overall=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.devstatus.summary.beans.BranchOverallBean@4131b89[count=0,lastUpdated=<null>,lastUpdatedTimestamp=<null>],byInstanceType={}]},errors=[],configErrors=[]], devSummaryJson={\"cachedValue\":{\"errors\":[],\"configErrors\":[],\"summary\":{\"pullrequest\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"stateCount\":0,\"state\":\"OPEN\",\"details\":{\"openCount\":0,\"mergedCount\":0,\"declinedCount\":0,\"total\":0},\"open\":true},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"build\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"failedBuildCount\":0,\"successfulBuildCount\":0,\"unknownBuildCount\":0},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"review\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"stateCount\":0,\"state\":null,\"dueDate\":null,\"overDue\":false,\"completed\":false},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"deployment-environment\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"topEnvironments\":[],\"showProjects\":false,\"successfulCount\":0},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"repository\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"branch\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null},\"byInstanceType\":{}}}},\"isStale\":true}}"}}]}
```

So I want to use Regex to get the content inside **devSummaryJson={}** block

I have try with **devSummaryJson={.*** but it return a few extra characters

```
devSummaryJson={\"cachedValue\":{\"errors\":[],\"configErrors\":[],\"summary\":{\"pullrequest\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":1,\"lastUpdated\":\"2022-12-19T09:09:46.366+0100\",\"stateCount\":1,\"state\":\"MERGED\",\"details\":{\"openCount\":0,\"mergedCount\":1,\"declinedCount\":2,\"total\":3},\"open\":false},\"byInstanceType\":{\"stash\":{\"count\":1,\"name\":\"Bitbucket Server\"}}},\"build\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"failedBuildCount\":0,\"successfulBuildCount\":0,\"unknownBuildCount\":0},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"review\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"stateCount\":0,\"state\":null,\"dueDate\":null,\"overDue\":false,\"completed\":false},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"deployment-environment\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null,\"topEnvironments\":[],\"showProjects\":false,\"successfulCount\":0},\"byInstanceType\":{}},\"repository\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":1,\"lastUpdated\":\"2022-12-19T09:09:46.000+0100\"},\"byInstanceType\":{\"stash\":{\"count\":1,\"name\":\"Bitbucket Server\"}}},\"branch\":{\"overall\":{\"count\":0,\"lastUpdated\":null},\"byInstanceType\":{}}}},\"isStale\":false}}"}}]}.
```

So Is there any way to solve this problem? (Removing exactly three specific characters at the end is not preferred, due to in the future maybe have change the json format)

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not use a json parser on the json string. then json parse again on the property that holds the json string?

Comment: Hi @Buttered_Toast, due to the string value inside `customfield_10000` so complex and i don't know how to deal with it to get the content inside `devSummaryJson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest regex: `"devSummaryJson={.*(?=}]})"gm`

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Sk7MXq/1)

- `(?=}]})` is a positive lookahead. It searches everything before three specific characters `}]}`.
- `devSummaryJson={.*` the position where the search starts.

Anyway, regex is not applicable for this type of problem and the best solution would be using a json parser.

Comment: 'regex' are the wrong tool for this problem. Use the json module of python to parse the json document. Hint `json.loads(data)'

Comment: Hi all, could you show me example how to parser that json with python code to get content inside `devSummaryJson`.

Comment: @NguyễnTriMẫn please explore this answer please explore this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771071/20666497. Or google a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your support. I have find the solution as your suggestion.

First: parser the json to the string
[image]
Second: Use Regex to get the content `devSummaryJson`
[image]
I'll try with groovy and post in here for anyone need.

P/S: Add groovy code to get content by parser Json and Regex
[image]

--> Result
[image]